# Legal array assignment statements in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)
>   [Difference between char *str = “…” and char str[N] = “…”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121759/difference-between-char-str-and-char-strn)

I am a beginner in C programming. I am confused over these things:

```
char ar[]="hello";
char ar2[], *ar3;
ar2=ar;
ar3=ar;
```

Also is the above legal in case of 2D arrays like:

```
int arr[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
int arr1[2][2],**arr2,*arr3;
arr1[0]=arr[0];
arr1=arr;
arr2=arr;
arr3=arr;
```

The other confusion was that I have seen above valid in case of structure.

```
struct test{
int ar[2];
} t1, t2;

int main()
{
t1.ar[0]=0;
t1.ar[1]=1;
t2.ar=t1.ar;
}
```

Please bear with me, I am a beginner in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char ar[] = "hello";
char ar2[];
char *ar3;
```

An array is a *non-modifiable lvalue*, so the following statement is invalid:

```
ar2 = ar;
```

Otherwise, it is possible to affect this value to a pointer.

```
ar3 = ar;
```

The behavior is the same with 2D arrays and structure members.

> ## C11 (n1570)
>
> **§ 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type [...].
>
> **§ 6.5.16 Assignment operators**
> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

Comment: I think 6.3.2.1/6.5.16 plus the same in layman terms (e.g. "arrays are not assignable to") is enough.