# Strings in Structures in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)
>   [Difference between char *str = “…” and char str[N] = “…”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121759/difference-between-char-str-and-char-strn)

I have a structure defined as:

```
typedef struct
{
  bool                  configured;
  bool                  active;
  uint32                lastComms;
  uint32                rxChRvdTime;
  char                  *name;
}vehicle;
```

and I initialize it as follows:

```
static vehicle *myVehicle;
```

When I want to initialize the name, I use:

```
myVehicle->name = "helloworld";
```

And this works fine. But when I wan't to set it to something other than a string literal, I seem to run into problems.

```
char *tmpName = "foobar";
strcpy(myVehicle->name, tmpName);
```

So why doesn't strcpy work? Do I somehow need to preallocate the string size in the structure before hand?  Should I not be using a pointer for the 'name' field, since there can only be one vehicle?

Comment: __"Do I somehow need to preallocate the string size in the structure before hand?"__

Comment: ok, noob question: why not simply do `myVehicle->name = tmpName;`

Comment: I disagree. This question is about allocation of memory for strings within structs. I read that question and it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate memory to copy into:

```
 myVehicle->name = malloc(strlen(tmpName) + 1);
 if (myVehicle->name)
 {
     strcpy(myVehicle->name, tmpName);
 }
```

as `myVehicle->name` is an uninitialised `char*`. If you `malloc()` you need to `free()`. The assignment to the string literal works because you making `name` point to the address of the string literal, which exists for the lifetime of the program.

But before this, you need to allocate memory for `myVehicle` itself:

```
myVehicle = malloc(sizeof(*myVehicle));
```

or just make `myVehicle` an object rather than a pointer:

```
static vehicle myVehicle;
```

Comment: when allocating memory for myVehicle or for name, i get a compiler error: "a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "vehicle *" "

Comment: @shred444, you need to `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: hmjd, you're a c monster. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
  myVehicle->name = strdup("foobar");
```

but don't forget to `free` it later.

Actually, you usually don't `strdup` constant literal strings (but you need to do that if that string could be overwritten later, since constant literal strings usually stay in read-only segments, and writing into them is undefined behavior.). You might build a string in some buffer, and `strdup` that buffer. A more realistic example might be:

```
 char buf[32];
 static int counter;
 counter++;
 snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "#%d", counter);
 myVehicle->name = strdup(buf);
```

Comment: No, idea. So +1 to balance it out again.

Answer (score 0):

You only declared a pointer, not actual memory it points to. try:

```
char *tmpName = "foobar";
myVehicle->name = malloc(strlen(tmpName) + 1);
if (myVehicle->name)
    strcpy(myVehicle->name, tmpName);
else
{
    // error
}
```

Don't forget to free `myVehicle->name` once you are done with it.

Comment: wow. 32 seconds after i posted?  Thanks!  So when the function that this is contained in finishes, the code wont automatically clear the declared tmpName space?  How does it know that I will still be using it later?

Comment: It will not be cleared, as you called malloc, and malloc'd memory is persistant until you explicitly free it (`free(myVehicle->name)`). If you lose the pointer before freeing the buffer, no one will clean it for you and you will get a memory leak.