# What does sizeof(&array) return?

Tags: c, string, pointers, sizeof

Following the question: [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10    
char str2[N]={"Hello"};
int main(){
    printf("sizeof(str2): %d bytes\n", sizeof(str2));
    printf("sizeof(&str2): %d bytes\n", sizeof(&str2));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof(str2): 10 bytes
sizeof(&str2): 4 bytes
```

I know that `str2` alone is the address of the first element in array `str2`. And that when `str2` is an argument of `sizeof` it returns the size of the whole array str2.

In addition, `&str2` is also the address of the first element in arr `str2` but from different type (`char (*)[N]` == pointer to array). But how does `&str2` behave when it's an argument of `sizeof`?

Comment: "I know that `str2` alone is the adress of the first element in array `str2`" - well, it isn't. It is converted to a pointer to its first element in most contexts, but `sizeof` is one of the exceptions.

Comment: @DanielFischer so why `printf("%p %p",str2, str2+1);` prints the adress of the first and second element respectively?

Comment: @user1980750 Because that is not one of the exceptions. Unless it is the operand of `sizeof`, `_Alignof` or the address operator `&`, or, in the case of string literals, as an initializer for a `char[]`, an expression of array type is converted to a pointer to the array's first element. So in _most_ contexts, the name of an array evaluates to a pointer to its first element, but it _is_ something different (the name of an array).

Comment: @DanielFischer: `_Alignof` is not one of the exceptions, since `_Alignof` can only be applied to a parenthesized type name, not to an expression. That was an error in the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft, corrected in the published ISO C11 standard. (As for *why* `_Alignof` can't be applied to an expression, that's a different question.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Meanwhile, I know that. I think it was you who told me, but it could also have been someone else. But thanks anyway, even if it's a repeated thanks.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Your second comment helps a lot, that's why I like a statement made by mathematician.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`&str2` is a pointer.  So you're just seeing the sizeof a pointer on your platform.

Comment: It is not *necessarily* the case that all pointer types are the same size, though it's true for most implementations.

Answer (score 119):

### Difference between `&str` and `str`,  when `str` is declared as `char str[10]`?

Read  [`sizeof`](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.4.html) Operator:

> **6.5.3.4 The sizeof operator, 1125:**
> When you apply the `sizeof` operator to an array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array.

So, according to your declaration, `sizeof(str2)` gives the complete array size that is 10 bytes (because N is defined as 10, and char size is 1-byte).
Whereas in the expression `sizeof(&str2)`, `&str2` is an address of an array and the size of that address is 4 bytes on your system. (address size may 8 bytes in some systems e.g 64-bit).

> In addition, `&str2` is also the address of the first element in arr `str2`?

**No**, value-wise both  `&str2` and `str` are the same, but **semantically both are different**. One is an address of an array of 10 chars while the other is an address of a char.

**One** difference you have seen in your own example between them is (@ouah explained this in an answer).

- type of `str` is `char[10]`
- type of `&str` is `char(*)[10]`

**Second:**
Following a diagram will help you observe the other difference.

```
for declaration: 
#define N 10
char str2[N] = {"Hello"};

str2 Array in memory is something like:
----------------------------------------

str
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----++----+
|'H' |'e' |'l' |'l' |'o' |'\0'|'\0'|'\0'|'\0'|'\0'|| '@'|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----++----+
 201   202  203 204  205   206  207  208  209  210   211
▲ ▲     ▲                                             ▲
| |     |                                             |
|(str2) (str2 + 1)                                    | 
|                                                     |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|201                                                  | 
|                                                     |
|                                                     |
(&str2) = 201                           (&str2 + 1) = 211


* assuming str address start from 201
* str[N] is 10 char long 201-210, partially initialized
* at uninitialized position, str2[i] = '\0'
* location 211 is unallocated, having garbage value,
  access to this location is illegal-Undefined Behavior
```

For the above diagram you can write code like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10    
int main(){
   char str2[N]={"Hello"};
  
   printf("\n %p, %p\n",str2, str2+1);
   printf("\n %p, %p\n",(&str2), (&str2+1));
}
```

Output:

```
 0xbf67e142, 0xbf67e143

 0xbf67e142, 0xbf67e14c
```

A [link for codepad:](http://codepad.org/CoA38yfG)

Notice that at the first line, the output address differ by one byte, but in the second, the difference is 10 bytes because it's the *array's* pointer (as shown in the diagram above).

According to the rules of pointer arithmetics, when you add 1 to a pointer variable, it starts to point to the next element of its own type. That's the reason for the 10 byte difference because `&str2` is an address pointing to an array.

**Third** difference:

By doing `*str2` you can access the first element. Whereas `*(&str2)` will not give you  the first element, instead, it will give the address of the first element.

An example will help here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10    
int main(){
   char str2[N]={"Hello"};
   printf("\n%p %c, %p %c\n",str2, *(str2), *(&str2), **(&str2));
}
```

output:

```
0xbf587046 H, 0xbf587046 H
```

[Codepad link](http://codepad.org/NVkigDFh)

In output

```
str2 gives  0xbf587046 
*(str2)     H 
*(&str2)    0xbf587046 
**(&str2)   H
```

That means `*(&str2) == str2` and value is address. And hence `*(str2) = **(&str2)` values is `H`.

**Edit:**  Above I shown difference between `&str` and `str` where `str` is an array of type `char[10]`.

### Difference between `char *str` and `char str[]` and how both are stored in memory

Suppose we have two declarations like below:

```
char *str1 = "hello";   
char str2[] = "hello";
```

In the above declarations `str1` is a pointer to `char`, that points to a constant string literal (by holding address of the first char `h` in `"hello"` string).

A string in C is of `char[N]` (array) type that is why `sizeof("hello")` gives 6 because `"hello"` string is 6 chars long array (included `\0` nul, strings termination, type of hello is `char[6]`).

In memory your `"hello"` string is stored like this:

```
 str1         23   24   25   26   27   28
+----+      +----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 23 |      | h  | e  |  l | l  | o  | \0 |    
+----+      +----+----+----+----+----+----+
   +-----------▲

here the address of the hello string is the first address = 23.  
str1: is a pointer capable of storing an address. 
"hello" consists of 6 chars
```

`char* str1 = "hello";` basically stores an address of a string hello to a pointer variable `str1` as I show in the above figure.

Note: If you want, you can change `str1` to point some other string. But you can't modify `hello` string. for example following code is valid:

```
 char* str1 = "hello";  // str1 points to hello  str1-->"hello"
 str1 = "world";  //Now, str1 points to world  str1-->"world"
```

Now `str1` points to other constant string world.

```
 str1         93   94   95   96   97   98 
+----+      +----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 93 |      | w  | o  |  r | l  | d  | \0 |    
+----+      +----+----+----+----+----+----+
   +-----------▲

here address of world string is first address = 93.  
str1: value change to point string world.
```

Important to note: `str1` points to constant strings hence you can't modify the string by accessing/indexing memory location for example `str1[i] = 'A'`;  will be illegal because you are *writing on read only memory* and behavior of this is undefined at runtime (although no compilation error because syntactically it's correct).

Again, because `str1` is a pointer `sizeof(str1)` will give 4 on same machine.

My following code and its run:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   char* str1="Hello";
   printf("\nstr1: %s, address: %p, sizeof(str1): %u", str1, str1, sizeof(str1));
   str1 = "world";
   printf("\nstr1: %s, address: %p, sizeof(str1): %u", str1, str1, sizeof(str1));
   return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
str1: Hello, address: 0x80485e8, sizeof(str1): 4
str1: world, address: 0x8048619, sizeof(str1): 4
```

[Codepad link](http://codepad.org/8vYnoiAu)

So, to assign a new string I simply assign an address of a new string. But I can't call `strcpy()` that will try to write on a read only memory location and that is illegal.

In the second declaration `char str2[] = "hello";`, `str2[]` is an `\0` terminated array of chars (or string) but NOT a pointer. Notice because in this declaration size is not given *default size*, we see that the size of the constant string "hello" that is 6. Type of `str2` is `char[6]`.

When we do `char str2[] = "hello";` an array of char is created and hello string will be copied into that array. So `str2` is not simply a pointer, but an array storing a complete string.

Conceptually it's like

```
       str2:
       103  104  105  106  107  108
      +----+----+----+----+----+----+
      | h  | e  |  l | l  | o  | \0 |    
      +----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

In this case lately in your code you are **not** allowed to do `str2[] = "world";` or `str2 = "world"`, it will be compile time error.

Example Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 char str2[] = "hello";
 str2[] = "world";
 str2 = "world"; 
 return 1; 
}
```

Compilation errors:

```
In function 'main':
Line 4: error: expected expression before ']' token
Line 5: error: incompatible types in assignment
```

[Codescape link](http://codepad.org/xbB11CmK)

Where this array `str2` is not a constant, we can modify its content for example doing `str2[2] = 'A'` is perfectly valid. We can also call strcpy to change content (and address space will not change)

```
       strcpy(str2, "world");

       str2:
       103  104  105  106  107  108
      +----+----+----+----+----+----+
      | w  | o  |  r | l  | d  | \0 |    
      +----+----+----+----+----+----+

      Note that when "world" is copied into a same memory space, the addresses of both "world" and "hello"
      string are the same.
```

Code Example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 char str2[] = "hello";
 printf("\nstr2: %s, address: %p, sizeof(str2): %u", str2, str2, sizeof(str2));
 str2[2] = 'A';
 printf("\nstr2: %s, address: %p, sizeof(str2): %u", str2, str2, sizeof(str2));
 strcpy(str2, "world");
 printf("\nstr2: %s, address: %p, sizeof(str2): %u", str2, str2, sizeof(str2));
 return 1; 
}
```

**Output:**

```
str2: hello, address: 0xbf58d056, sizeof(str2): 6
str2: heAlo, address: 0xbf58d056, sizeof(str2): 6
str2: world, address: 0xbf58d056, sizeof(str2): 6
```

[Codepad link](http://codepad.org/6ZI9NB1Q)

Note: string values are different on same address space. `sizeof(str2)` = 6 perfectly understood from older answer that is size of array in bytes.

To read similar description about 2-dimensional array, read: [Difference between `char* str[]` and `char str[][]` and how both stores in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564608/what-does-the-variable-name-mean-in-case-of-array-of-char-pointers/17661444#17661444)

Answer (score 12):

`str2` is of type `char [10]` (i.e, array `10 of`char`)

`&str2` is of type `char (*)[10]` (i.e., pointer to an array `10` of `char`).

So `sizeof (&str2)`  yields the size of an objet of pointer type `char (*)[10]`

Answer (score 2):

If you simply use the variable `arr` (as defined `char arr[10]`), it always *decays* to a const pointer `char *const arr` pointing to the first element. While `&arr` results in a pointer `char (*)[10]` that **includes** the size of `arr`, i.g. `10`.