# about sizeof(char *) and sizeof(char[])

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, sizeof

```
char *str1 = "pupupupu";
char str2[] = "pupupupu";

printf("%s\t%d\n", str1, (int)sizeof(str1));
printf("%s\t%d\n", str2, (int)sizeof(str2));
```

Output:

```
pupupupu    8
pupupupu    9
```

My question: Why are the two output sizes different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(str1)` is size of char pointer where as `sizeof(str2)` gives size of array that is string length (`pupupupu`) + 1

Read my this answer, its not exactly same but help you much: [What does sizeof(&arr) returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-returns/15177499#15177499)

Comment: because my computer is X64,so size of a pointer is 8bit,it makes me confused before(my example string has 8 chars),thank you for your answer!

Comment: @pupu007 Yes PuPu..you correctly got the point