# Difference between array and pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, strcpy

Yesterday I had a little trouble with a homemade "strcpy" function. It works now though but I'm a little confused!

```
char* a = "Hello, World!"; //Works
char b[] = "Hello, World!"; //Works also

strcpy(a, "Hello!"); //Segmentation fault
strcpy(b, "Haha!!"); //Works..
```

Where is the difference? Why does the char pointer cause a "Segmentation fault"?

Why does this even work? :

```
char* a = "Haha"; //works
a = "LOL"; //works..
```

Comment: Read this section of the C FAQ : http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html

Comment: I removed the C++ tag since this is about the C subset (and even there you wouldn't implement `strcpy` yourself).

Comment: Read: [Difference between `char *str` and `char str[]` and how both stores in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarray-return/15177499#15177499)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
char* a = "Hello, World!";
```

gives you a pointer to a string literal.  A string literal may exist in read only memory so its contents cannot be changed.

```
char* a = "Haha"; //works
a = "LOL"; //works..
```

changes the pointer `a` to point to a different string literal.  It doesn't attempt to modify the contents of either string literal so is safe/correct.

```
char b[] = "Hello, World!"
```

declares an array on the stack and initialises it with the contents of a string literal.  Stack memory is writeable so its perfectly safe to change the contents of this memory.

Comment: so I cannot modify even a single character in the char pointer, right?

Comment: @NormalPeopleScareMe That's right. It's pointing to a string *constant*.

Comment: Well, it's undefined behavior, so it might work or it might not. My advice is to always assume it won't.

Comment: @NormalPeopleScareMe It depends what it points to.  You can't modify the contents of a pointer to a string literal but you can modify the contents of a pointer to a stack or heap allocated string.

Comment: Thank you guys. Simonc, you helped me really a lot!

Comment: Compiling with `-Wwrite-strings` will tell gcc to remember how constant string literals are: It will give you a warning on this code.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example since you are trying to write to a read only memory pointed by a,you will get the segmentation fault.If you want to use pointers then allocate the memory on heap,use and delete it after its use.
Where as b is an array of chars initialized with "Hello, World!".

In the second example you are making the pointer to point to different string literal which should be fine.

Comment: I find this answer very helpful. I didn't know that the string literal is located in the read only memory. Also I found a tutorial how to use char pointers in combination with strcpy which caused a segmentation fault here and they were allocating memory and i couldn't retrace why they did it. Thanks.