# int a[20], what's the answer of " &a + 4"?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int a[20];
```

Suppose the address of a[20] in memory is 100. Size of int is 4.
It's easy to know that `a = 100, &a = 100, &a[4] = 116`.
But when I try (&a + 4),the answer is 420(I have test it in GCC ,DEV-C ,VC )
I guess the reason why `&a + 4 = 420` is `420 = 100 + 4 * sizeof (a[20]) = 100 + 4*(4*20)`

(The above" = " means "equal")

Is that right?

Comment: This sounds like homework.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw it in the book "Pointers on C". But its answer is 116. I test the code in three different kind of compilers . Still not sure the reason.

Comment: No , answer is 420.  You can try it yourself

Comment: @MarounMaroun The OP already told you the answer and why. Before claiming otherwise, have the good grace to test it and maybe reexamine your understanding of C.

Comment: @JimBalter My bad. I've just figured out my mistake, but that's why we're here :) to correct and help each other.

Comment: Read this I exampled [differences between &array and array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-returns/15177499#15177499)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the answer is that the behavior is undefined.

`&a` is the address of the array. Adding `1` to an address (pointer value) advances it by the size of the type that it points to. But pointer arithmetic is valid *only* when the result points to an element of the same array as the original pointer, or just past the end of it. (For purposes of pointer arithmetic, a single object is treated as an array of one element.)

*If* you assume a certain "well-behaved" memory model, with a single linear monolithic addressing space and addresses sensibly related to integers, then given your assumptions (`&a` is 100, `sizeof (int) == 4`), then yes, the result of `&a + 4` would be `420`. More precisely, since `420` is an integer, not a pointer, it would be `(int(*)[10])420` -- again, assuming conversions between pointers and integers are particularly well behaved.

Answer (score 5):

`&a` is a pointer to an array of int with 20 elements (the type is `int (*)[20]`).

So `&a + 4` is different than `a + 4` since in the second expression `a` evaluates to a pointer to the first element (it evaluates to a pointer of type `int*`). The pointer arithmetic works out differently since the pointer types are different, even though the value of `&a` and `a` are the same.

Comment: Your comment isn't any better.

Answer (score 3):

Because the size of a is the size of the array, which is 80 bytes.  So 4 * 80 = 320 + the base address of 100 = 420.

When you add to a pointer, it adds the entire size of the thing you're pointing at for each size.

So, yes.  You're right.