# Why sizeof(array) and sizeof(&array[0]) gives different results?

Tags: c, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    char array[20];

    printf( "\nSize of array is %d\n", sizeof(array) );  //outputs 20
    printf("\nSize of &array[0] is %d\n", sizeof(&array[0]); //output 4
}
```

Code above gives `20` for `sizeof(array)` and `4` for `sizeof(&array[0])`.

What I knew was instead of giving array as a argument, its first element can be passed. Shouldn't they give same output as 20? and why `&array[0]` gives 4 as result? char is stored in 1 byte as far as I know?

Comment: read this: [What does sizeof(&arr) returns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-returns/15177499#15177499)

Comment: note: [`sizeof(array)/sizeof(&array[0])`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009725/weird-behavior-when-printing-array-in-c/18009736#18009736) give you length == 20

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the expression `sizeof array`, `array` is not converted to a pointer type.

> #### C11, § 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
>
> Except **when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator**, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

Therefore, its type is `char[20]`, not `char *`. The size of this type is `sizeof(char) * 20 = 20` bytes.

> #### C11, § 6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators
>
> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size is determined from the type of the operand**.

`&array[0]` type is `char *`. That's why the `sizeof(&array[0])` gives the same result as `sizeof(char *)` (4 bytes on your machine).

Answer (score 10):

The variable `array` is an array of 20 `char`, the value of the expression `sizeof(array)` is equal to the sizeof bytes of an array of 20 `chars`, which is `20`.

`&array[0]` is a *pointer*. The `sizeof` returns the size of a pointer, which is 4 in your machine.

Answer (score 5):

The expression `&array[0]` is a *pointer* so the `sizeof` operator returns the size of the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(array)` is giving you size of total array and `sizeof(&array[0])` is giving you `sizeof(char *)`

Your question is perfect example of `Array and pointer are not same`. Array may act as pointer.[Have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

`&array[0]` returns a pointer to the first index of array. Using the `sizeof` operator on a pointer will yield the size of a pointer (depends on ABI), in your case, it's 4.

Comment: *"Using the sizeof operator on a pointer will **always** yield 4."* - That's not true..

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(&array[0])` is returning the size of a pointer to a char. `array[0]` yields a char, the `&` returns a pointer to the char. Your compiler used 4 bytes for a pointer (32 bit).

Answer (score -1):

The "array" itself is constant pointer, you can not address it to different location. Yes, array address is the same as &array[0], which is derived from &*(array+0) and it is equal to &*(array). We know that &* is eliminated so we are back to "array" again. So "array" is the same as "&*(array+0)" 
But in regards to sizeof operator, the operand must be in array notation, not in pointer notation. 
To clarify:

char *data = {"Today is Sunday"}; ... Pointer notation

char data[] = {"Today is Sunday"}; ... Array notation

In the first example with pointer notation the sizeof(data) will be the size of bytes required to store an address, which is 8 on my system. In the second example the sizeof(data) will give the number of bytes occupied by the array, which would be 15 chars in the string. But if you use pointer notation like sizeof(data+0) the result will be the number of bytes required to store an address, which is 8 on my system.

sizeof operator result is the same for pointer and for array with pointer notation.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. With `char *data = "something";` you have `data`, a pointer to `char`, yet with `char data[] = "something";` you have `data`, an array of `char`. Arrays _decay_ to pointers to their first elements in most expressions, but not when they are operands to `sizeof`. Pointer notation versus array notation has to do with array indexing, not pointer initialization (first example) or array initialization (second example).

Answer (score -2):

I think that "array" itself is constant pointer, you can not address it to different location. 
It is true that we can write: array is the same as &array[0], which is derived from &*(array+0) and it is equal to &*(array).  We know that &* is eliminated so we are back to "array" again. So "array" is the same as "&*(array+0)"
The terms should be the same in some circumstances, but it is not the same for the sizeof operator.