# function in C to print char content

Tags: c, function, char, printf

I'm trying to create a function in C to print the content of the char variable.

Here is my code for the function itself:

```
void printChar(char ChArr[])
{
    int iCharLen = sizeof(ChArr); // define ChArr[] length
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<iCharLen; i++)
    {
        printf("%c",ChArr[i]);
    }     
}
```

Here is the code for "int main()":

```
int main()
{  
  char ChAr[] = "A very long char!!!!";
  printChar(ChAr[]);  
  return 0;
}
```

And the error I got is: "error: expected expression before ']' token"

The error is for line where I call the printChar().

Note: This code is for C only.

Comment: This code is broken on so many levels, you should probably pick up a text book on C or at least take some tutorials first. To fix the compilation error you need to remove the [] after ChAr, but the code won't do what you want anyway (hint sizeof does not work that way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the [] when passing the character array to the function. Hence your function call will look like this:

```
printChar(ChAr);
```

This will solve the compiler error.

In addition, use `strlen(ChArr)` in the function definition instead of `sizeof(ChArr)`.

Only then will all the characters in the array be displayed.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare:

```
char ChAr[] = "A very long char!!!!";
```

the default size of `ChAr[]` array is the size of the string you used in the definition/initialization of the array.

After that, in any expression `ChAr[]` is not a valid, and you have to give some index value within `[]`; this the reason you are getting an error like:

```
"error: expected expression before ']' token"
```

It means, in call of function:

```
printChar(ChAr[]); 
               ^  before ] you are missing some index value
```

Additionally, even if you call it like `printChar(ChAr[i]);` it won't compile (not correct) and will give a type mismatch error.  According to your function declaration below:

```
void printChar(char ChArr[]){
                    ^ you need an char*
```

you should call this function as:

```
printChar(ChAr);
```

Because type of `ChAr` is `char[N]` which is what the function `printChar` accepts as an argument.

Next error in function `printChar()` is that evaluating length of string using `sizeof` operator is wrong; use `strlen()` instead of `sizeof` operator. That means:

```
 int iCharLen = sizeof(ChArr); // define ChArr[] length
```

should be:

```
 int iCharLen = strlen(ChArr); // define ChArr[] length
```

Don't forget to `#include <string.h>`.

Remember in function declaration `char ChArr[]` is same as `char* ChArr`.

The `sizeof()` operator returns size of array only if an array name is given, but in your function you are passing the address of `char*` that doesn't return length of your string; instead, it gives `sizeof` pointer variable `ChAr` (usually 4 bytes or 8 bytes).

To understand how `sizeof()` operator  works in both case read: [What does sizeof(&arr) return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-return/15177499#15177499)

Comment: Thx for explanation! Understood the mistake. Fixed it. Now Works

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Thanks to fix my trivial typos. I notice [revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17638597/revisions)  carefully, I will take care/ improve my answers.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the [] when calling the function:

```
printChar(ChAr);
```

Also, `sizeof` in the function will return the size of a pointer to char, not the number of chars in the array. This is probably not what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do a my_putchar func, here it is:

```
void my_putchar(char c)
{
write(1, &c, 1);
}

int main()
{
my_putchar('a'); // for example
}
```

and with that you can also more fancy stuff like my_putstr or my_puts func

```
void my_putstr(char *str)
{
int i;

i = 0;
while(str[i] != '\0')
{
my_putchar(str[i]);
i++;
}
}
```

or more short

```
void my_putstr(char *str)
{
write(1, str, strlen(str));
}
```

it can do:

```
int main()
{
my_putstr("abcdef");
}
```

hope this help you :)