# what's the difference between the return value of a malloc() and an array name

Tags: c, pointers

for example, I have

```
char* c=(char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
printf("0x%x,c);
printf("0x%x,&c);
```

and this will shows different value for `c` and `&c`.

However,if i m having the following:

```
char d[100];
printf("0x%x,d);
printf("0x%x,&d);
```

this shows that value of `d` and `&d` are the same.

How comes the first code gives me the different result for `c` and `&c`?

Comment: Did you mean to declare `char* c` instead on the malloc?

Comment: @ChrisO ya, that was an typo. thanks. I corrected it.

Comment: Read: [What does sizeof(&arr) return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-return/15177499#15177499) Explains difference between `d`, `&d`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An array decays into a pointer to its first element in many contexts, including its use in a function call.  It *doesn't* decay when it's the operand of the unary `&` (address-of) operator.  That means `d` and `&d` yield the same address in your example, but have different types.  `char *` and `char (*)[100]`, respectively, in your case.

In contrast, `c` is a pointer.  When you take its address with `&`, you're getting the address of the pointer variable, as opposed to using `c` directly, which gives you the address it's pointing to.  `c` is a `char *`, and `&c` is a `char **`.

Editorial note:  Use `%p` to print pointer types.  `%x` is for an `unsigned int`, and `unsigned int` might be a different size from a pointer.  Corrected code might look like:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)c);
```