# Inconsistency in using pointer to an array and address of an array directly

Tags: c, pointers

This code sample prints the array correctly.

```
int b[2] = {1, 2};
int *c = &b;
int  i, j,k = 0;
for (i = 0;i < 2; i++) {
    printf("%d ", *(c+i));
}
```

while this one prints two garbage values.

```
int b[2] = {1, 2};
int  i, j,k = 0;
for (i = 0;i < 2; i++) {
    printf("%d ", *(&b+i));
}
```

why are the two code samples behaving differently?

Comment: What is `k` being used for?

Comment: second code - [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) so behaving differently

Comment: +1 nice question , but easily answerable , still useful :)

Comment: @Shubham read updated answer.

Answer (score 9):

The declaration:

```
int b[2] = {1, 2};
```

Creates an array of two `int` with values `1`, `2`.
Suppose in a system size of int is 4-bytes, then the array `b[]` should be stored in memory something like as follows:

```
first ele        +----------+                
     (b + 0) ---►|     1    | 0xbf5c787c  <----- &b ,    (c + 0)
next ele         +----------+ 
     (b + 1) ---►|     2    | 0xbf5c7880  <------------- (c + 1)
                 +----------+              
     (b + 2) ---►|     ?    | 0xbf5c7884  <----- (&b + 1) next array  
                 +----------+                    
             ---►|     ?    | 0xbf5c7888  
                 +----------+ 
             ---►|     ?    | 0xbf5c788c  <----- (&b + 2) next array  
                 +----------+      
             ---►|     ?    | 0xbf5c7890
                 +----------+               

? means garbage value
b[] array in memory from 0xbf5c787c to 0xbf5c7880  
each cell is four bytes
```

In above diagram memory cells with value `?`  means garbage values and not allocated (memory from `0xbf5c7884` is not allocated in for our array). The values `1`, `2` are stored in memory at address `0xbf5c787c` and `0xbf5c7880`, that is allocated in array `b[]`.

Let's instead of printing values, we print addresses of memory that you access in your code using `(c + i)` and `(&b + i)`, for this consider following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int b[2] = {1, 2}; 
  int  i = 0;
  int *c = &b; //Give warning: "assignment from incompatible pointer type" 
  printf("\n C address: ");  // outputs correct values 
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("%p ", (void*)(c + i));
  }
  printf("\n B address: ");  // outputs incorrect values/ and behaving differently 
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("%p ", (void*)(&b + i));  // Undefined behavior 
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Outputs:

```
 C address: 0xbf5c787c 0xbf5c7880 
 B address: 0xbf5c787c 0xbf5c7884
```

Check this code working @[Codepade](http://codepad.org/XYEUXMOV)
Notice, `(c + i)` prints correct address of cells with value `1`, `2` hence outputs in your first code is correct. Whereas `(&b + i)` prints address value that is not allocated to array `b[]` (that is outside of array `b[]`) And accessing this memory gives undefined behaviour(unpredictable) at runtime.

Actually there is difference between `b` and `&b`.

- `b` is an array and its type is `int[2]`, `b` decays into `int*` as address for first element in most  expressions (read: [some exceptions where array name not decaying into a pointer to first element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752978/exception-to-array-not-decaying-into-a-pointer/17753057#17753057)). And `b + 1` points to next `int` elements in array (notice the diagram).
- `&b` is address of complete array and its type is `int(*)[2]`,  `(&b + 1)` points to next array of type `int[2]` that is not allocated in your program (notice in diagram that where `(&b + 1)` points).

To know some other interesting differences between `b` and `&b` read: [What does `sizeof(&array)` return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-return/15177499#15177499)

In first code snipe, when you do `c = &b`, you are assigning array's address to `int*` (in our example `0xbf5c787c`). With GCC compiler this statement will give warning: "assignment from incompatible pointer type".
Because `c`  is pointer to `int`, so  `*(c + i)` prints integer stored at address `(c + i)`. For  `i =  1`  the value `(c + 1)` points to second element in array (in our example at `0xbf5c7880`) hence `*(c + 1)` prints `2` correctly.

Regarding assignment `int *c = &b;` in first code I highly suggest read @AndreyT's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17681597/1673391) below. The correct and simple way to access array elements using pointer will be as follows:

```
int b[2] = {1, 2};
int *c = b;   // removed &, `c` is pointer to int  
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    printf("%d ", *(c + i)); 
 // printf("%d ", c[i]); // is also correct statement 
}
```

In your second code, adding `i` to `&b` make it pointing to outside allocated memory and in printf statement you access memory using `*` dereference  operator cause invalid memory access and behavior of this code at run time is [Undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). That is the reason that second piece of code behaving differently at different execution.

Your code compiles because syntactically it correct, But at runtime accessing of unallocated memory can be detected by OS kernel. This may causes OS kernel send a signal core dump to the process which caused the exception (interesting to note: as OS detects memory right violation by a process -- An invalid access to valid memory gives: SIGSEGV, and access to an invalid address gives: SIGBUS). In worth case your program may execute without any failure and produce garbage results.

Regarding second code, correct way to print array using 'pointer to array' will be as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int b[2] = {1, 2}; 
  int  i;
  int (*c)[2] = &b;   // `c` is pointer to int array of size 2
  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
     printf(" b[%d] = (*c)[%d] = %d\n", i, i, (*c)[i]); // notice (*c)[i]
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
b[0] = (*c)[0] = 1
b[1] = (*c)[1] = 2
```

Check @[codepade](http://codepad.org/vXLIFnCz). Point  to be notice parenthesis around `*c` is needed as precedence of `[]` operator is higher then `*`  dereference  operator (whereas if you use pointer to int you don't need parentheses as in above code).

Comment: "This statement should give you Warning for type mismatch assignment." — Not necessarily; a pointer to array converts implicitly to a pointer to its first element. IMHO this is a crucial detail.

Comment: @Potatoswatter  But I just checked with GCC I got:`assignment from incompatible pointer type`. Should I remove this??

Comment: @Potatoswatter: That's not true. *Array itself* converts implicitly to a pointer to its first element. *Pointer to an array* does not convert implicitly to a pointer to the first element. The initialization in first code sample is erroneous, i.e. it is a constraint violation. This is why compiler complains about it.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Nope, looks like I was wrong. Actually even wronger than came out in that comment. Good thing I just reviewed; Andrey is right.

Answer (score 5):

This is because of the pointer type to which the pointer arithmetic operation `ptr+i` is applied:

- In the first case, you add `i` to a pointer to `int`, which is the same as indexing an array. Since the pointer to an array is the same as the pointer to its first element, the code works.
- In the second case, you add `i` to a pointer to an array of two `int`s. Therefore, the addition puts you beyond the allocated memory, causing undefined behavior.

Here is a quick illustration of this point:

```
int b[2] = {1,2};
printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n", (void*)&b, (void*)(&b+1), (void*)(&b+2));
```

On a system with 32-bit `int`s this prints addresses separated by eight bytes - the size of `int[2]`:

```
0xbfbd2e58
0xbfbd2e60
0xbfbd2e68
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int *c = &b;
```

This is actually not valid. You need a cast.

```
int *c = (int *) &b;
```

The two expressions:

```
 *(c+i)

 and 

 *(&b+i)
```

are not same. In the first expression `i` is added to a `int *` and in the second expression `i` is added to a `int (*)[2]`. With `int *c = (int *) &b;` you convert a `int (*)[2]` to an `int *`. `c + i` points to the `i`-th `int` element of `c` but `&b+i` points to the `int [2]` element of `b` moving the pointer value outside the actual array object.

Comment: It's true that `int *c = &b;` is not valid, but adding a cast is not the solution. If you want the address of the first element, write `int *c = b;` or `int *c = &b[0];`. If you want the address of the array, write `int (*c)[2] = &b;`. Converting a pointer from one type to another (incompatible) type is rarely the answer -- unless you're asking a rather odd question.

Comment: @KeithThompson I read @Andrey's answer, having doubt that "Is it possible that with some architecture/compiler `int *c = &b;` give undefined behaviour **?** Can I ignore warning generated  by compiler as I know value-wise both `&b` and `b` are same (semantically both are different).

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Given that `b` is of type `arr[2]`, `int *c = &b;` is a constraint violation. A conforming compiler *must* diagnose it and *may* reject it. If it rejects it, its behavior is not merely undefined; it has no behavior. Just don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

The first code is broken. The assignment

```
int *c = &b;
```

is invalid. The right-hand side has type `int (*)[2]`, while the object on the left has type `int *`. These are different, incompatible types. The compiler should have told you about this error by issuing a diagnostic message. Don't ignore diagnostic messages issued by compilers.

The code, despite suffering from the above problem, was accepted by the compiler due to a non-standard compiler extension, which allowed the compiler to convert `int (*)[2]` pointer to `int *` type preserving the numerical value of the pointer (the physical address). So, you ended up with `int *` pointer pointing to the beginning of your `int [2]` array. Not surprisingly, accessing memory through that pointer lets you to see the contents of the array.

Your second code is also broken in more than one way. It doesn't suffer from the first problem, since you don't force any conversion of `&b` value (which, again, has type `int (*)[2]`) to anything else, but apply pointer arithmetic directly to `&b`. According to the rules of pointer arithmetic, the expression `&b + 1` produces a pointer that points beyond the original `b` array. Dereferencing such pointer is illegal. So, `*(&b + 1)` already produces undefined behavior. On top of that, the expression `*(&b + 1)` has type `int [2]`, which decays to pointer type `int *`. So, in your second code you are attempting to print an `int *` value with `%d` format specifier. This is also undefined behavior. The manifestations of that undefined behavior is what you see in your second example.

In other words, in the first piece of code you got luckier than in the second one, which is why the output of the former looks more meaningful.

Comment: Andrey Is it possible that with some architecture/compiler `int *c = &b;` give undefined behaviour **?** As I know value wise both `&b` and `b` are same but semantically both are different, so I feel a code because of  `int *c = &b;` compiles with warning but I can ignore this warning. Is my assumption is correct?