# C++ pointers expression and array

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int value = 5; 
int a[ ] = {2,4,6,9,3,5,7}; 
int *q1 = &value; 
int *q2 = a; 
int *q3 = &a[2]; 
int *p[ ] = { q1, q2, q3 }; 

cout<<p[0][0]<<" " <<p[1][1] <<" " <<p[2][3];

answer is 5 4 5.
```

May I know that how can I get the answer? I'm confused, thanks for guides!

Comment: I'm confused too. What do you expect answer to be and how does it differ from what you're getting?

Comment: No, i don't get it how can I get the value as shown...

Comment: `dynamic array allocation` not used in your code so I corrected the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to know:

1. An expression `a[i]` is equivalent to  `*(a + i)`, and so an expression `a[i][j]` is equivalent to `*(a[i] + j)` that is also equivalent to `*(*(a + i) + j)`.
2. When you assign array name to a pointer it decays into  address of first element address for example:

   ```
    int a[ ] = {2, 4, 6, 9, 3, 5, 7}; 
    int *q2 = a;
   ```

   Now `q2` points to first element that is `a[0]`.

   Read also some [exceptions where array name not decaying into a pointer to first element?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17753057/1673391) ably answered by @[H<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529758/h2co3).
3. When you add `i` to a pointer `p` it start pointing to `ith` element location from `p` address. So suppose id `p` points to second element in array `p + 3` points to fifth element in array (similarly subtraction works in opposite direction). Read [10.2 Pointers and Arrays; Pointer Arithmetic](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html) and [Pointer Arithmetic](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html).

To answer your question: In Code:

```
int value = 5; 
//          0  1  2  3  4  5  6 
int a[ ] = {2, 4, 6, 9, 3, 5, 7}; 
int *q1 = &value; 
int *q2 = a;  // address of array a decays into address of first element
int *q3 = &a[2]; 
int *p[ ] = { q1, q2, q3 };  // can be written as below
```

last line equivalent to:

```
int *p [] = { &value, a, &a[2]};
```

Pointer `P` is an array of `pointer to int` so `p[i]` means address, and `p[i][j]` is int value:

```
 p[0][0] == *(p[0] + 0) == *(&value + 0) ==  *&value == value  == 5
 p[1][1] == *(p[1] + 0) == *(a + 1) ==  a[1] == 4
 p[2][3] == *(p[2] + 3) == *(&a[2] + 3) 
           //            0  1  2  3  4  5  6 
           //int a[ ] = {2, 4, 6, 9, 3, 5, 7};
           //                    +1 +1 +1
                        == that is value at 3rd location from index 2
                        == a[5]  == 5
// When you add 1 to an address pointer start pointing to next location
```

@From [Dyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp): You can understand last expression as:
Expression `*(&a[2] + 3)` is defined as `*(&*(a+2) + 3)`, which is equal to `*(a+5)` and the same as `a[5]`:

```
 p[2][3] == *(p[2] + 3) == *(&a[2] + 3) == *(&*(a+2) + 3) 
                                        == *((a+2) + 3)
                                        == *(a + 2 + 3)
                                        == *(a + 5) == a[5] == 5
```

Hope this help.

Comment: `*(&a[2] + 3)` is defined as `*(&*(a+2) + 3)`, which is equal to `*(a+5)` and the same as `a[5]`.

Comment: @DyP Nice expiation I want to add in my answer.

Comment: @user2611244 read: [Pointer Arithmetic](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan alright, I'm so glad that I received a lot of info here!