# Why does printing out variables in C change their values?

Tags: c, pointers

I just write a simple program in C as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int *pointer;
  int number = 4;
  printf("number = %d\n",number);
  pointer = &number;
  printf("number = %d and pointer = %d\n",number,pointer);
  printf("pointer = %d and number = %d",pointer,number);
}
```

and afer execution it prints the output like:

```
number = 4 and pointer = 8724
pointer = 8724 and number = 9415
```

So, why is the value changing only for orientation change of printing. I can't justify the rule.

Comment: It's because of Heisenberg.

Comment: [Huh, can't reproduce that.](http://ideone.com/4VuSHr)

Comment: Your code and output don't match - the first `printf()` doesn't seem to be printed. Make sure you show your actual code and a real execution's output.

Comment: This is undefined behavior. Why you people always assume that a pointer is an `int`? I mean, how come? It isn't. It **obviously** isn't. Never try to treat it as one. It's undefined behavior.

Comment: @H2CO3 some local books (specially DOS) give this wrong information.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Aw, that's sad. Very sad.

Comment: The important point here from what @H2CO3 said is that the actual value of the variable `number` is unchanged — it remains 4. It's just that `printf` is printing it incorrectly because it probably only got halfway through printing a (64-bit, probably) pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using a 64-bit compilation?

```
int number = 4;
int *pointer = &number;
printf("number = %d and pointer = %d\n", number, pointer);
printf("pointer = %d and number = %d\n", pointer, number);
```

If so, the first `printf()` call in the code above pushes a 4-byte `int` value and an 8-byte `int *` value onto the stack, and tells `printf()` to print two 4-byte quantities.  These are apparently the 4-byte `int` and 4 bytes of the 8-byte address.  The second `printf()` call pushes an 8-byte `int *` and a 4-byte `int` onto the stack, and tells `printf()` to print two 4-byte quantities again.  This time, though, they are the two halves of the 8-byte `int *` value printed separately.  This is strictly invoking undefined behaviour, but it is one plausible possibility and would explain the result you saw.

*(There are some caveats lurking around.  I'm assuming that for a 64-bit compilation, `CHAR_BIT == 8`, `sizeof(int) == 4`, and `sizeof(int *) == 8`; also that the implementation passes arguments on the stack, and possibly some related assumptions that are not strictly guaranteed by the C standard but that do typically apply to 64-bit compilers.)*

You should decide what you're trying to do.  If you want to see `4` twice, then:

```
int number = 4;
int *pointer = &number;
printf("number = %d and pointer = %d\n", number, *pointer);
printf("pointer = %d and number = %d\n", *pointer, number);
```

If you want to see the address, then you should use `%p` for the address (and strictly cast to `void *`):

```
int number = 4;
int *pointer = &number;
printf("number = %d and pointer = %p\n", number, (void *)pointer);
printf("pointer = %p and number = %d\n", (void *)pointer, number);
```

If you want to control the format for the pointer, then you need C99 `#include <inttypes.h>` and:

```
int number = 4;
int *pointer = &number;
printf("number = %d and pointer = 0x%.16" PRIXPTR "\n", number, (uintptr_t)pointer);
printf("pointer = 0x%.16" PRIXPTR " and number = %d\n", (uintptr_t)pointer, number);
```

#### Example code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number = 4;
    int *pointer = &number;
    printf("number = %d and pointer = %d\n", number, pointer);
    printf("pointer = %d and number = %d\n", pointer, number);

    printf("number = %d and pointer = %d\n", number, *pointer);
    printf("pointer = %d and number = %d\n", *pointer, number);

    printf("number = %d and pointer = %p\n", number, (void *)pointer);
    printf("pointer = %p and number = %d\n", (void *)pointer, number);

    printf("number = %d and pointer = 0x%.16" PRIXPTR "\n", number, (uintptr_t)pointer);
    printf("pointer = 0x%.16" PRIXPTR " and number = %d\n", (uintptr_t)pointer, number);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Compilation with warnings

GCC 4.8.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.5.  Similar warnings are given by `clang` too.

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition   it.c -o it
it.c: In function ‘main’:
it.c:8:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("number = %d and pointer = %d\n", number, pointer);
     ^
it.c:9:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("pointer = %d and number = %d\n", pointer, number);
     ^
```

#### Example output

```
number = 4 and pointer = 1417245952
pointer = 1417245952 and number = 4
number = 4 and pointer = 4
pointer = 4 and number = 4
number = 4 and pointer = 0x7fff54797500
pointer = 0x7fff54797500 and number = 4
number = 4 and pointer = 0x00007FFF54797500
pointer = 0x00007FFF54797500 and number = 4
```

Interestingly, the system manages to print `4` for the number both times in the first two lines of output.  I've not studied the assembler to see how that works — but one of the beauties of invoking 'undefined behaviour' is that you cannot complain about the results; any result is valid precisely because the required behaviour is undefined.

Comment: What is `PRIXPTR` ?? I don't know. Is it macro like `PRIu32` ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan yes it is.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: `PRIXPTR` is the macro that defines the correct conversion specifier for a `uintptr_t` to be printed in upper-case hex.  It is related to `PRIu32` in that it comes from `<inttypes.h>`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks! Very interesting. One more question you uses `0x%.16" PRIXPTR` ? it means whether it is 32-bit or 64-bit machine you wants to print in `16` hex number prefixed by `0x`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: My whole answer is predicated on '64-bit', but yes, the `0x%.16" PRIXPTR` format does mean 16 hex digits, even though the 64-bit addresses only use 12 non-zero hex digits on my Mac (and it would mean 8 leading zeros if it were compiled in 32-bit).  See the recently added example output.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably due to undefined behavior! As you are passing incorrect format string for address.

Use `%p` to print address and typecase it to `void*`.

```
printf("number = %d and pointer = %p\n",number, (void*)pointer);
printf("pointer = %p and number = %d", (void*)pointer, number);
```

The fprintf function which `printf`'s section refers back to for the format string paragraph:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.[...]

text taken from  @Shafik Yaghmour' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19136941/1673391)

Answer (score 1):

Use `*pointer` instead of `pointer`.

`Pointer` prints address and `*pointer` prints value.

```
printf("number = %d and pointer = %d\n",number, *pointer);  
                                                ^ 
printf("pointer = %d and number = %d",*pointer,number);
                                      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using a platform where the size of an `int` and the size of a pointer are different, or perhaps less likely the parameter passing is different for pointers and ints. There's a mismatch between the type you are trying to print (`%d`) and the type you are passing (int/pointer in the first case and pointer/int in the second).