# Why the compiler is not showing error on expressions that use arrays like pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm new in C programming and currently learning about array and strings. I'm quite confuse in this topic. Coming to my question-

1. Since an array (for ex- `a[]={20,44,4,8}`), the name in an expression decays into pointer constant,so whenever if i try to do pointer arithmetic for example- `a=a+1` or anything like this the compiler shows error but when the same thing I write in printf() function it is showing the address of the first element rather than showing error. Why?
2. In an expression for example `*(a+1)=2` first `(a+1)` will be evaluated and then `*` will dereference it. My question is that if `a` is a pointer constant then how it can point to any other memory location in an array and how this expression is perfectly legal?

I tried to search about this but couldn't get the accurate result.

Comment: Well, `a` is an array and is not a pointer. You cannot assign to a variable whose type is an array. What would that mean?

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130236/array-increment-operator-in-c

Comment: This question has two parts. While the first part is adequately covered by the dupe, the second one is not. I am voting to reopen this question so that OP could get an answer to the second part of his question.

Answer (score 2):

Although an array name evaluates to a pointer in some expressions, your `a = a+1` assignment tries to assign to an array, which is not allowed.

On the other hand, `a+1` expression is allowed, and it evaluates to another pointer. When you pass this value to `printf`, the function happily prints it. Do not forget to cast the result to `void*` when you print:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)(a+1));
```

> if `a` is a pointer constant then how it can point to any other memory location in an array and how is `*(a+1)` expression perfectly legal?

For the same reason that `2+3`, a combination of two constants, produces a value that is neither a 2 nor a 3. In your example, `a+1` expression does not modify `a`. Instead, the expression uses it as a "starting point", computes a different value (which happens to be of type pointer), and leaves `a` unchanged.

Comment: so what does a+1 mean actually?

Comment: @user3788135 According to C pointer arithmetic rules `a+1` means exactly the same thing as `&a[1]`.

Comment: As far as i understand from you answer and comment is that pointer arthematic in pointer and array are little different.Right? Will you please give me some advice so that i can be a good programmer.if you like to. :)

Comment: @user3788135: pointer arithemtic is the same for pointers and array expressions.  For any pointer `p` to type `T`, the expression `p + 1` will give the address of the next object of type `T`.  For example, if `T` is `char` and `p` is `0x8000`, then `p + 1` will evaluate to `0x8001` because the next `char` object starts at the next byte.  If `T` is a 32-bit `int`, then `p + 1` will evaluate to `0x8004` because the next `int` object starts 4 bytes from the current byte.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the array `a` is not quite the same as a pointer constant. It merely
acts like a pointer constant in some circumstances. In other circumstances it will
act quite differently; for example, `sizeof(a)` may have a much larger value
than `sizeof(b)` where `b` is truly a pointer.

This code is legal:

```
int a[] = {20,44,4,8};
int *b;
b = a;
b = b + 1;
```

because `a` is enough like a pointer that you can set `b` to point to the same
address but, unlike `a`, `b` really *is* a pointer and it can be modified.

The last line of code could just as well be:

```
b = a + 1;
```

because the right-hand side here is not trying to modify `a`; it is merely using
the address of the first element of `a` to compute a new address.

The expression `*(a + 1)` is effectively another way of writing `a[1]`.
You know what will happen when you write `a[1] = 2`, right?
It will change what is stored in the second element of `a`.
(The first element is always `a[0]` whether you do anything with it or not.)
Storing a new value in `a[1]` doesn't change the location of the array `a`.

Answer (score 0):

When array decays in to pointer, the resulting value is a *rvalue*. It's an value that cannot be assigned to.

So `int[4]` will become `int*const`, *constant* pointer to integer.

**Q1:**

Types in expression `a = a + 1` are:

```
int[4] = int[4] + int
```

If we focus on addition first, array decays to pointer:

```
int[4] = int*const + int
int[4] = int*const        // After addition
```

But now there is a problem:

```
int*const = int*const
```

In memory `a` is an array with 4 `int`s, and nothing more. There is no place where you could possibly store address with type `int*`. Compiler will show an error.

**Q2:**

Types in expression `*(a+1)=2` are:

```
*(int[4] + int) = int
```

Again, array decays to pointer and addition happens:

```
*(int*const + int) = int
*(int*const) = int        // int* is now equal to &a[1]
```

Dereferencing `int*const` is legal. While pointer is constant, value it points to is not:

```
int = int  // Ok, equal types
```

Types are now perfectly compatible.