# If int (*p_arr)[10] is defined as a pointer to an array of size 10 then why compiler shows warning in this case?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, pointer-to-array

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {0};
    int *p1_arr = arr;
    int (*p2_arr)[10] = arr;      // Line 7, Shows Warning here

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

On compiling on `gcc` using `gcc -g -Wall LengthofArray.c`, it shows following warning:

```
gcc: LengthOfArray.c:7: [Warning] assignment from incompatible 
                         pointer type [enabled by default]
```

My question is if `int (*p2_arr)[10]` is a pointer to an array of size 10, then why compiler shows this warning?

Also what is the correct way then?

I used gcc 4.7.2 on Windows 7 32-bit (DevC++)
and also checked on gcc 4.1.2 on SLES 10.3 x86_64

Comment: The point to understand is both `&arr` and `arr` both semantically different. (of-course value is same if you print using `%p`).

Comment: Read [What does `sizeof(&array)` return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarray-return/15177499#15177499)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... if int (*p2_arr)[10] is a **pointer to an array of size 10** ...

As `p2_arr` points to an array of size 10, you need to assign an *address* of an array of size 10:

```
int (*p2_arr)[10] = &arr;
```

Comment: Right, I got confused. The name of array is an `int` pointer not a pointer to `array of 10 ints`. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @0xF1: The name of the array names the array, not an `int` pointer. An array is **converted** to a pointer to its first element in most expressions, but not all of them. So you can see that the name of the array does indeed name the array in `sizeof`, `&`, and `_Alignof` expressions.

Comment: @tfinniga This is C, not C++. No warning will/shall be emitted if you assign **any** (non-qualified) object pointer type to a `void *`.

Answer (score 4):

`arr` (as any array) decays into a pointer to its **first element** (and *not* to a pointer to the array itself), which is an `int *`. To get the correct behavior, take its address, like this:

```
p2_arr = &arr;
```

Comment: @tfinniga Um what? That's wrong. `arr` is not the same as `&arr[0]`, it only is implicitly converted so. (Don't downvote if you don't know what's going on...)

Comment: @tfinniga And even if it was: your "reasoning" is simply nonsense. What's with all those "strict types"? Just wrong. It's just that OP tries to assign to a pointer to an incompatible type.

Comment: @tfinniga (as to why the explanation is nonsense: it's a classic non sequitur. There's no such thing as a "more strict type", there are only compatible and incompatible types. I suggest you read the relevant parts of the standard before criticizing others' answers in an unjust way.)

Comment: after reading the question and your answer more carefully, I must apologize.  I misunderstood your answer, which I now see is correct.

Comment: @tfinniga I've edited my answer so it's not locked - if you downvoted, could you revoke it?

Comment: Sure thing.  I tried to switch to an upvote earlier, but as you guessed it was locked; I just switched my vote.  Again, sorry for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

### Why compiler says *assignment from incompatible pointer type* ?

- `arr` is converted to type ***pointer to int***

  Name of the array decays into a pointer of type, *`pointer-to-T`* to the array's first element. (Exceptions to this are : when the array is the operand of a `sizeof` or `&` operator, or is a string literal initializer for a character array. Read **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752978/exception-to-array-not-decaying-into-a-pointer)**) `T` is type of array element.
- `p2_arr` is of type ***pointer to array of 10 int***

  This is self explanatory and clear from your declaration of `p2_arr`

Hence, you can't assign `arr` to  `p2_arr`

---

### Solution:

Now, to assign a valid pointer expression to `p2_arr`, you will need *address of array of 10 int*.

- `&arr`  is of type ***pointer to array of 10 int***

You can do,

```
int (*p2_arr)[10] = &arr;
```