# Pointer to array of pointer to char vs. pointer to pointer to char (or char** argv vs. char* (*argv)[])

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, program-entry-point

I had a discussion with a colleague today regarding his (for me) unusual 'main' function signature. He likes to declare it like so:

```
int main(int argc, char* (*argv)[]) {
   printf("at index 0: %s\n", (*argv)[0]);
}
```

while I usually write the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("at index 0: %s\n", argv[0]);
}
```

Sometimes i write "char* argv[]", to make it more clear that argv is an array of pointers to chars.

The code in the first example does compile with a warning

```
warning: second argument of ‘main’ should be ‘char **’
```

but it works. My question is WHY the code works, as I had expected a crash due to dereferencing argv. Does the compiler *know* that the function signature is different, and allows (*argv) as a kind of "no-operation" here?

Trying to understand what's going on, I wrote the following example, which to my surprise does not crash either and prints "first" (but the compiler emits a warning):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_function(int argc, char* (*argv)[])
{
    printf("at index 0: %s\n", (*argv)[0]);
}

int main(void)
{
    char* stringArr[] = { "frist",
                          NULL };
    size_t stringArrSz = sizeof(stringArr)/sizeof(*stringArr);

    return my_function(stringArrSz, stringArr);
}
```

I had expected that I would need to pass "&stringArr" (use the address operator) to make the code run. That - of course - works too, and fixes the compiler warning.

Please let my know if my question is unclear, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213580/difference-between-char-argv-and-char-argv-for-the-second-argument-to-main

Comment: Remember that for function arguments `[]` is translated as a pointer. So `char *argv[]` is really `char **argv`. Now think a little what `char *(*argv)[]` might be translated to...

Comment: Also note that the C specification tells what the types of the arguments to `main` is. Deviate from that and your program is no longer valid. I recommend you read e.g. [this `main` function reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If I'm not mistaken `char* (*argv)[]` should translate to `char*** argv`. What i don't unterstand is why dereferencing argv still works, even if the address of operator was not used when when passing argv to `main`.

Comment: @karacho84 - Your comment differs from your question! Which one is correct? Anyway - `char* (*argv)[]` is  just wrong. The warning kind of tell you that.

Comment: @karacho84 It's pure luck it works. And that luck is because of how memory and pointers are laid out and handled on modern PC-like systems. In reality it's *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @AbhinavRisal thank you, but that is the code i usually write, either `char* argv[]` or `char** argv`, which are, to my understanding, the same thing for the compiler. What my colleague writes is `char* (*argv)[]`, which would be equal to `char*** argv` if I'm not mistaken. (Edit: SO deleted some of the asterisk, deleted and added again with inline code formatting)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I would assume _undefined behavior_ miraculously working here, too. Thank you!

Comment: @4386427 corrected the comment, sorry. The formatter removed the `*`s :)

Comment: It is very strange that your sample program prints “first” when the source code contains “frist”. Is there a spell-checker built into your compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is WHY the code works, as I had expected a crash due to dereferencing argv. Does the compiler know that the function signature is different, and allows (*argv) as a kind of "no-operation" here?

"Appearing to work as intended" is one of the possible outcomes of undefined behavior.

A valid pointer value is still being passed for `argv` from the runtime environment, so I would not expect the code to crash just from accessing `argv[0]`, regardless of how it was declared.

Where things will get interesting is when you try to access `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, etc.  While the C language itself doesn't guarantee that pointers to different object types have the same size, in practice they do on most modern architectures like `x86`; IOW, `sizeof (T *)` == `sizeof (T **)` == `sizeof ( T *** )`.  Thus, `p + 1` should yield the same byte offset for each of those types on that platform.

Your colleague is flirting with disaster, though.  Types do matter, and if you were working on a system where different pointer types had different sizes, declaring `argv` as `char *(*)[]` instead of `char *[]` or `char **` could have some unexpected consequences.