# "sizeof" to know the size of an array doesn't work in a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, sizeof

```
int main()
{
int laiArreglo[] = {5,8,2,3,1,4,6,9,2,10}, liElemento;

printf("\nInsert the number: ");
            scanf("%d", &liElemento);
            ShowNumber(laiArreglo);
return 0;
}




void ShowNumber(int laiArreglo[])
{
    int liContador;

    printf("\nNumbers: ");

    for (liContador = 0; liContador < sizeof (laiArreglo) / sizeof (int); liContador++)
    {
        printf("%d ", laiArreglo[liContador]);
    }
}
```

I was using (sizeof (laiArreglo) / sizeof (int)) in main and it worked perfectly but, now **inside of a fuction it doesn't work, why?**.

Comment: Because it's a pointer rather than an array.

Comment: The parameter of `ShowNumber` is an `int*`. You have to pass an extra argument denoting the size of the array to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that the **The name of an array ["decays"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) to a pointer to its first element**.When you use

```
sizeof(laiArreglo)
```

from `main`,it evaluates to

```
10*sizeof(int)
```

and not

```
sizeof(int*)
```

as it is [one of the cases where decay dosen't happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752978/exception-to-array-not-decaying-into-a-pointer).

When you use

```
ShowNumber(laiArreglo);
```

to pass it to a function, the decay does occur. So the above statement is equivalent to

```
ShowNumber(&laiArreglo[0]);
```

and when you use

```
sizeof(laiArreglo)
```

from the function `ShowNumber`, it evaluates to

```
sizeof(int*)
```

as `laiArreglo` is a pointer to `int` pointing to the address of the first element of the array `laiArreglo`.

Answer (score 1):

In your function `ShowNumber()`,what you past is a **pointer** rather than an **array**.