# Why sizes of an array and a pointer to a first element are different?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Kernighan & Ritchie 2nd ed. says:

> The correspondence between indexing and pointer arithmetic is very close. By definition, the value of a variable or expression of type array is the address of element zero of the array. Thus after the assignment
>   `pa = &a[0];`
>
> **`pa` and `a` have identical values.** Since the name of an array is a synonym for the location of the initial element, the assignment `pa=&a[0]` can also be written as
>   `pa = a;`

If `a` and `pa` are identical, then why this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[] = "hello";
    char *pa = a;
    printf("Array: %ld\n", sizeof(a));
    printf("Pointer: %ld\n", sizeof(pa));
}
```

Outputs this:

```
Array: 6
Pointer: 8
```

Reference to an authoritative source would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two objects can have the same address but their sizes can be different.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
>   may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size is
>   determined from the type of the operand**....

Consider the following example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    struct A
    {
        char c;
        int x;
    } a;

    printf( "object a:\taddress - %p size - %zu\n",
            &a, sizeof( a ) );
    printf( "object a.c:\taddress - %p size - %zu\n",
            &a.c, sizeof( a.c ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
object a:   address - 0x7fff164e16d0 size - 8
object a.c: address - 0x7fff164e16d0 size - 1
```

As it is seen the object `a` of type `struct A` and its data member `c` of type `char` have the same address but different sizes.

As for arrays then a pointer is an object that stores an address of other object. To store an address of other object it is enough to allocate for example 4 or 8 bytes of memory for the pointer depending on the used system.

As for arrays then they are named extents of memory. Arrays do not store addresses. They store their own elements (that of course can be pointers).

An array name used in expressions is converted to pointer to its first element.

According to the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’** that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

In this quote there is listed when an array is not converted to a pointer to its first element. For example when an array is the operand of `sizeof` operator.

If to return to your program

```
int main()
{
    char a[] = "hello";
    char *pa = a;
    printf("Array: %ld\n", sizeof(a));
    printf("Pointer: %ld\n", sizeof(pa));
}
```

then in this statement

```
    char a[] = "hello";
```

string literal `"Hello"` that has type `char[6]` is not converted to a pointer.
However in this statement

```
    char *pa = a;
```

array `a` is converted to pointer to its first element.

And in this statement

```
    printf("Array: %ld\n", sizeof(a));
```

array `a` is not converted to a pointer because it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator.

However if you used an expression in the sizeof operator for example like this

```
sizeof( a + 0 )
```

then you would get a pointer and correspondingly the `sizeof` would return the size of the pointer instead of the size of the array

Answer (score 2):

They do indeed have identical **values**. But that **doesn't** mean they are the same thing.

`a` is **still** a fixed-sized array. `pa` is **still** a pointer.

`sizeof` is one operator that recognises this difference.

Your array has 6 elements of size `char` (`sizeof(char)` is defined by the standard to be 1). (The 6th element is the string null terminator).

`sizeof(char*)` is 8 on your system. It's probably 64 bit.

Comment: Detail: "They do indeed have identical values"  Disagree that `pa` and `a` have the same value.  IMO, `a[]` has a 6 `char` _value_.  In the context of `char *pa = a;`, the expression `a` is converted to a `char *` with a value of of the initial element of `a` and that is assigned to `pa`.  Yet `a` does not have the value of a pointer.

Comment: I know what you're saying, but I say the *values* are equal though the *types* are different.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are not pointers. The array name *decays* to a pointer to its first element in many cases, but `sizeof` is one of the few exceptions.

> #### C11 §6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
>
> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

Comment: `_Alignof` should be out of the exception list!

Comment: @haccks Source? I'm quoting from the draft of the standard.

Comment: That's a **bug** in the standard. See what C11 standard says: *The `_Alignof` operator yields the alignment requirement of its operand type. The
operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant. **When applied to an array
type, the result is the alignment requirement of the element type**.* (6.5.3.4 p3).

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `pa` are not identical. Always remember: **Arrays are not pointers**. When used in an expression arrays are converted to pointer to its first element with some exception including as an operand of `sizeof` operator.
`sizeof(a)` will give the size of array while `sizeof(pa)` will give the size of pointer.

Comment: There's a handful of contexts that don't decay arrays, unary `&` is also one of them.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17753057/3233393 for what seems to be a full list :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 char a[] = "hello";
 char *pa = a;
```

Here `sizeof(a)` will give size of array `a` . And `sizeof(pa)` will give size of pointer `pa`.Both are different .

Also as in function arguments array decays to pointer but this one is exception along with `&`.

Also while printing type `size_t` you should use specifier `%zu` (as specified in ANSI C99).