# Difference between array and &array[0]

Tags: c, pointers

`int array[] = {1,2,3,4};`

As I understand, `array` is just a pointer to `&array[0]`

But how come then `sizeof(array);` knows size of an array and not just that it's only 4 byte number?

Comment: A good question. The answer is, of course, that `array` is not just a pointer. It just "decays" to one in the most frequently occuring contexts, namely on the right side of an assignment and as function arguments.

Comment: Another somewhat esoteric example is `printf("%p == %p but %p != %p!\n", array, &array, array+1,&array+1);`. I.e while `array` and `&array` have the same numerical values, they still have different types: `&array` is a pointer to, one wouldn't believe it, an array whose size is 4*sizeof(int), and consequently `&array+1` advances the pointer by that size, e.g. 16 or 32 bytes.

Comment: How many times has 'an array is not a pointer' been posted here?

Comment: @PeterSchneider thanks alot your answer actually connected the dots for me . !

Comment: @MartinJames I originally wanted to close as dup but then didn't find a post which *exactly* asks this question. (To be sure, it has been said millions of times, but mostly in the context of "why can I not assign" or "my program crashes here, why" etc.).

Comment: Related : [Exception to array not decaying into a pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752978/exception-to-array-not-decaying-into-a-pointer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`, and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

Arrays in C don't store any metadata about their size or anything else, nor is any storage set aside for any sort of pointer.  They're laid out pretty much as follows:

```
     +---+
arr: | 1 | arr[0]
     +---+
     | 2 | arr[1]
     +---+
     | 3 | arr[2]
     +---+
     | 4 | arr[3]
     +---+
```

There's no separate storage for a variable `arr` apart from the array elements themselves.  As you can see, the address of `arr` and the address of `arr[0]` are the same.  This is why the expressions `arr`, `&arr`, and `&arr[0]` all give you the same *value* (the address of the first element), even though the *types* of those expressions are different.

Except when the operand is a variable-length array, the result of `sizeof` is computed at compile time, and the compiler treats array operands as arrays in those circumstances; otherwise, it treats the array expression as a pointer to the first element.

Comment: I would argue that the value of `arr` is all 4 elements. It is just that `printf` (or anybody else, for that matter) cannot see that because it just receives the pointer after the argument passing. Admittedly the argument is bordering on ontology.

Answer (score 7):

Although the name of the array does become a pointer to its initial member in certain contexts (such as passing the array to a function) the name of the array refers to that array as a whole, not only to the pointer to the initial member.

This manifests itself in taking the size of the array through `sizeof` operator.

Comment: With ordinary pointer arithmetics it doesn't show, only with multi dimensional arrays. Oh, and also if you take the address of the array; I think that's what you meant. Correct.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Thank you for the comment! I removed the part where I talk about pointer arithmetics to avoid confusion, because the rules remain the same, as long as the pointer is of proper type.

Answer (score 0):

No, `array` is not just a pointer, as your `sizeof` example shows.
It is only that in most contexts, it is converted to `&array[0]`, but not in all.

Answer (score 0):

In this declaration -

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4};    // a is of array type
```

`a` becomes a pointer to first element of array `a` ( *after decay* ). Not in all cases both will be equal , but in cases such as when array is passed to function .

Answer (score 0):

This does only work within the scope where you define the array. If you pass your array to a function the sizeof operator doesn't work anymore. 
I'm not completely sure but I think that the compiler stores the length of the array and puts it back where you have sizeOf(array) like a macro but not dynamically. Please correct me if someone knows better.

Comment: That used to be the case before the advent of variable length arrays: sizeof() was known at compile time and as such acted like an int literal. It still is true for "normal" arrays. `sizeof()` of a variable length array, by contrast, must be computed at run time because it is only known at run time.