# Difference between &ar[0][0] and ar

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

When I print `ar` and `&ar[0][0]` as pointers, I see the same value.
so I'm expecting them to be interchangeable, However, that is not the case:

[image]

```c
int main(void)
{
    #define rowsCount 4
    #define colsCount 3
    int ar[rowsCount][colsCount] =
    {
        {0, 1, 2},
        {3, 4, 5},
        {6, 7, 8},
        {9, 10, 11},
    };
    int rowIndex = 1;
    int colIndex = 5;


    printf("TEST: %p %p\n", ar, &ar[0][0]);
    printf("%d\n", ar[rowIndex][colIndex]);
    printf("%d\n", *(&ar[0][0] + rowIndex * colsCount + colIndex));
    printf("%d\n", *(ar + rowIndex * colsCount + colIndex));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler generates a warning for the fourth `printf` "C4477: 'printf' : format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int *' "

Comment: You can change the last print to `printf("%d\n", *((int*)ar + rowIndex * colsCount + colIndex));`

Comment: Also relevant : [Difference between array and &array\[0\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035068/difference-between-array-and-array0).

Comment: @WeatherVane, I'm working on codeblocks with GNU GCC and I have 0 warnings in it. Not sure what compiler/IDE are you using. Also an explanation is preferred.

Comment: @klutt, thanks for the fix. but in case of saying just ar, what is the type of the pointer if it's not `int *` ?

Comment: `ar` is not a pointer. It's an array.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker, I don't think the linked question answers mine.

Comment: @klutt, don't arrays decay to pointers ?

Comment: MSVC compiled from a command line, no IDE. There should be a setting for you somewhere, or an option. The `ar` is a different type from `&ar[0][0]`, and so the pointer arithmetic works differently. `sizeof ar` is `48` so `ar + 1` would add `48` to the address.

Comment: @Youssef13 Yes, they sometimes do.

Comment: @Youssef13 : the answers to the linked question explain that while the memory address is the same, the type is different for both expressions. This in turn means that `sizeof` and pointer arithmetic will work differently for them. That should answer your question of why they're not interchangeable - if it doesn't, you might want to clarify your question.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I printed `ar` and `ar + 1`, the difference was 12 only not 48. so it seems adding 1 jumps to the next row instead of the next element. Am I right ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker, Thanks for clarification. I understood that arithmetic is different now. but is what I'm saying in the previous comment correct ?

Comment: @Youssef13 In this case, it decays to a pointer of type `int (*)[3]`.

Comment: @klutt, Thanks! this really clarified much of the thing to me.
so that clarifies why even *(ar + 1) doesn't print the element at ar[1][0]

Comment: It also clarifies the warning stated by @WeatherVane.

Comment: @Youssef13 What it clarifies is why you ALWAYS should enable warnings when the code is not behaving the way you want.

Comment: @klutt, I've left codeblocks with its default settings. and I sometimes get warnings, but not sure why not all warnings. is there a specific compiler flag I should enable ?

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra` is a good start. You could also add `-pedantic`. It can also be a good thing to specify your desired C version (usually a modern one unless you have reasons to do otherwise) with `-std=c18`

Comment: @klutt, They were disabled, but even after enabling them I still don't get warnings for it.

Comment: @Youssef13 Then it's a bug or you're doing something wrong. That's something you could post a question about. :)