# What is the difference between these two pointer assignments in C?

Tags: arrays, c

I have been doing a lot of research and also playing around with code, but I'm still confused with this:
Why is case 1 erroring?

Case 1:

```
int arr[] = {0,4,7};
int *p = arr[0]; // pointer points to the first element in the array

printf("%d", ++*p);
// This results in Segmentation fault
```

Case 2:

```
int arr[] = {0,4,7};
int *p = arr; // pointer points to the first element in the array

printf("%d", ++*p);
// This prints 1
```

Comment: `int *p = arr[0];` should be `int *p = &arr[0];` `arr[0]` isn't the address of the first element. It's the first element. If you want the address of the first element you need the `&` operator. `arr[i]` is synonymous with `*(arr + i)`. There was a recent CPP con video on pointers (like... two days ago) by Ben Saks. If you're on this subject, [take a look](https://youtu.be/rqVWj0aVSxg).

Comment: @JohnFilleau OH. I see. Thank you!

Comment: The [code](https://godbolt.org/z/znqcr9) doesn't even compile, so there's no question of segfaults. Please paste the exact code that gives the error.

Comment: arr[0] is the first element in the array, also it is a pointer, points the first. But arr is not just a pointer.

Comment: Also this is duplicated question. Please reference on here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035068/difference-between-array-and-array0

Comment: @G.Alexander — `arr[0]` is **not** a pointer.

Comment: `int *p = arr[0];` is incorrect code, if you do not see an error message then adjust your compiler settings as it causes you to waste time by not stopping at this error .

Answer (score 2):

In case 1: `arr[0]` is an `int` value. `int *p = arr[0];` is an error.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between these two pointer assignments in C?

Firstly, one thing common with both is that neither is an assignment.

> ```
> int *p = arr[0]; // pointer points to the first element in the array
> ```

The comment here is wrong. `arr` is an array of `int`. `arr[0]` is the first element of that array. It is an `int`. `int *p = arr[0]` is an attempt at initialising a pointer with the value that is stored in the array. However, the type doesn't match since the value is not a pointer. `int` is not implicitly convertible to `int*` and therefore the program is ill-formed.

A standard conforming language implementation is required to diagnose this issue for you. This is what my compiler says:

> ```
> error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'
> ```

---

> Why is case 1 erroring?

If the program even compiles, you are initialising a pointer with the value 0. This likely means that it is a null pointer and that it doesn't point to any object. `++*p` attempts to indirect through this null pointer and access the non-existing integer.

> ```
> int *p = arr; // pointer points to the first element in the array
> ```

Comment here is correct.

Comment: well they are both assignments

Comment: @pm100 Nope. They are declarations, and they are initialisations. They are not assignments.

Comment: C doesn't have "ill-formed" (nor "well-formed"). The program contains a constraint violation

Comment: @M.M Huh, I didn't notice that this was C (even though it is in the sentence I quoted). I answered this as C++, as per question tag.

Comment: @eerorika oh, the tags were edited after you answered and before I commented

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is throwing an error because you did not use '&' before assigning the value to the pointer. As it is a pointer so you can not assign a value to it. You can only use it to store addresses. I coded it in C++ and here is the correct form.I guess it helps.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int arr[] = {0,4,7};
  int *p = &arr[0]; //you are missing '&' before array[0]

  printf("%d", ++*p);
  system("pause");
  // This prints 1
  }
```