# How do I pass a pointer to a multidimensional array in C?

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional array that works with a function:

```
bool matrix[rows][cols];
func(rows, cols, matrix);

void func(int rows, int cols, bool matrix[rows][cols]) {
    //...
}
```

However, as soon as I try to have `matrix` in the original function modified by:

```
bool matrix[rows][cols];
func(rows, cols, &matrix);

void func(int rows, int cols, bool *matrix[rows][cols]) {
    //...
}
```

I receive an incompatible pointer type error. I am clueless as to why.

Comment: Just get rid of the `&` and the `*` and all should be well - arrays decay to pointers when passed as function parameters.

Comment: What errors do you get exactly?

Comment: @pytheos it is an incompatible pointer type. My bad - looked like a lot when I did my first modification.

Comment: @PaulR I wouldn't be able to modify both dimensions of the original matrix that way would I?

Comment: Well this is odd. I am able to modify both dimensions from the original function with the new function despite not passing in a pointer or address. This would have to spark a new question...

Comment: A couple things:  (1) You really want a pointer to the first element, just as with one-dimensional arrays.  (2) What you had would in fact have been a pointer to the array as a whole, except you declared the argument incorrectly.  The `*` needs to be grouped with `matrix`, so parentheses are needed.  But this isn't really what you want, as explained in 1.

Comment: `func(rows, cols, &matrix);

void func(int rows, int cols, bool (*matrix)[rows][cols]) {`

Comment: should be `bool (*matrix)[rows][cols]` . What you actually wrote is an array of `bool *`s

Comment: @Synlar trying to pass an array always passes a pointer

Comment: Is bool C++, or a user defined type?

Comment: @granmirupa `bool` is a macro for `_Bool`  defined in stdbool.h.

Comment: @Synlar When you get an error, please include the **exact** error message in your question.

Comment: @PaulR This isn't really a dup of that. That question is about `double a[]` vs `double* a` in function arguments while this is different. This question is about passing a pointer to the array which is very different.

Comment: @PaulR I agree with Cool Guy. The dup is far off.

Comment: @CoolGuy: I disagree, but go ahead and vote to re-open - check first for other dupes though, as I suspect there are many.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bool matrix[rows][cols]` is an array of arrays of a type `bool`

`bool* matrix[rows][cols]` is an array of arrays of a type pointer to `bool` or simply `bool*`.

Thus if you defined your function to take an array of arrays of type `bool*`, you need to pass that type:

```
bool* m[row][col];
func( row , col , m );
```

---

If you want to have a pointer to `bool matrix[rows][cols]`, then your approach is not correct.
 A pointer to matrix has the type: `bool (*pmatrix)[rows][cols]`. So define your function with that type and pass the address of the matrix array:

```
func( rows , cols , &matrix );
```

Answer (score 3):

[@2501](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082723/2501) [has already answered your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37097447/3049655), but, since you want the modified array to be reflected to the main function, you don't actually need a pointer to the array (which will complicate things more)! Just pass the array directly as you'll get the expected results!

Why, you ask?

Short answer: In C, arrays are passed by reference.

Long answer:

Always keep in mind that **when you use the name of an array, it gets converted to a pointer to its first element**<sup>†</sup>. This is commonly referred to as "[array decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/3049655)".

Coming back to your code, The diagram of `bool matrix[rows][cols];` would be:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|                     |                     |                     |                     |                     |
|     matrix[0][0]    |     matrix[0][1]    |     matrix[0][2]    |         ...         | matrix[0][cols - 1] |
|                     |                     |                     |                     |                     |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|                     |                     |                     |                     |                     |
|     matrix[1][0]    |     matrix[1][1]    |     matrix[1][2]    |         ...         | matrix[1][cols - 1] |
|                     |                     |                     |                     |                     |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|                     |                     |                     |                     |                     |
|         ...         |         ...         |         ...         |         ...         |         ...         |
|                     |                     |                     |                     |                     |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|                     |                     |                     |                     |                     |
| matrix[rows - 1][0] | matrix[rows - 1][1] | matrix[rows - 1][2] |         ...         | matrix[rows - 1][cols - 1] |
|                     |                     |                     |                     |                     |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

From the above diagram, it is clear that the first element of

```
bool matrix[rows][cols];
```

is the first subarray `matrix[0][0]` to `matrix[0][cols - 1]`. So what happens here is that **the address of this subarray is being passed to the function**. This is of type `bool (*)[cols]`. This would mean that

```
void func(int rows, int cols, bool matrix[rows][cols])
```

would work the same way as

```
void func(int rows, int cols, bool (*matrix)[cols])
```

So, for example, if you wanted to write to the third slot of the second subarray of `matrix`, you can use `matrix[1][2] = WHATEVER;` and the changes made from the function would also affect to the caller since the address was passed.

---

<sup>†</sup>: There are a few exceptions where array "decay" doesn't occur. See [Exception to array not decaying into a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17752978/3049655)

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to  a single dimensional array, say `int a[10]` may look like below:

```
int (*ptr)[10]
       |    |______________array of 10 integers(read type and number together)
       |______a pointer to ^
```

A pointer to a multi dimensional array, say `int a[10][10]` may look like below:

```
int (*ptr)[10][10]
      |    |     |_________________array of 10 integers(read type and number together)
      |    |______________array of ^ 
      |______a pointer to ^
```

**Warning:** Mind the parenthesis.

`*matrix[rows][cols])` is different from `(*matrix)[rows][cols])`. The difference is pointed out in the answer by @2501.

Answer (score -3):

You can use a `***` for a matrix.

`char ***matrix = alloc_matrix(BUFFER_SIZE, BUFFER_SIZE);`

```
char ***alloc_matrix(unsigned rows, unsigned columns) {
    char ***matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof(char **));
    if (!matrix) abort();

    for (unsigned row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        matrix[row] = calloc(columns, sizeof(char *));
        if (!matrix[row]) abort();
        for (unsigned column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            matrix[row][column] = NULL;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Here is an example where we use `malloc` and `pointers` to create a matrix.