# Why memory address contained by pointer +1 is different from address of value being pointed + 1

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Pointer stores memory address of value being pointed at so memory address contained by pointer is same as memory address of value. So adding 1 to both these memory addresses should yield same result, which is not happening. Why?
Here is the code

```
 int main()
 {
     int ages[] = {23, 43, 12, 89, 2};
     int *cur_ages = ages;

     printf("\n&cur_ages=%p, &cur_ages+1=%p", &cur_ages, &cur_ages+1);
     printf("\n&ages=%p, &ages+1=%p", &ages, &ages+1);
     printf("\ncur_ages=%p, cur_ages+1=%p", cur_ages, cur_ages+1);
     printf("\n*cur_ages=%d, *cur_ages+1=%d", *cur_ages, *(cur_ages+1));

     return 0;
 }
```

Output is

```
&cur_ages=0x1ffff85f3d0, &cur_ages+1=0x1ffff85f3d8
&ages=0x1ffff85f3dc, &ages+1=0x1ffff85f3f0
cur_ages=0x1ffff85f3dc, cur_ages+1=0x1ffff85f3e0
*cur_ages=23, *cur_ages+1=43
```

&ages+1 is not equal to cur_ages+1. Why?

Comment: Undefined behavior for passing non-`void*` arguments to `printf("%p")`. You may think this is pedantic, but the type of various objects is indeed at the very heart of the matter.

Comment: A pointer is not an address, and adding 1 to a pointer does not add 1 to the address.

Comment: @user2357112: In C terms, a pointer value *is* an "address". That's how the word "address" is used in the C standard. A C "address" is not the same as a machine-level "address".

Comment: Careful with your phrasing, @user2357112, a pointer IS an address with a type. Adding 1 to a pointer increases it by the size of its type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic increases the value of a pointer by the given value multiplied by the size of the type it points to.

So when you do this:

```
&ages+1
```

You take the address of `ages` (which is of type `int [5]`) and add `sizeof(ages)` to the pointer value.  Assuming `sizeof(int)` is 4, this adds 20 to the pointer value.

Likewise, when you do this:

```
cur_ages+1
```

Here, `cur_ages` points to a `int`, so adding 1 adds `sizeof(int)` to the pointer value.

Comment: This is a good example of why arrays and pointers are *not* the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

&cur_ages is the address where cur_ages is stored on the stack. Since &cur_ages+1 is 8 greater, I would assume this was done in 64 bit mode where the size of a pointer is 8 bytes.

&ages is similar to declaring int (*ptr_to_ages)[5], where ptr_to_ages is a pointer to an array of 5 integers, which could be a pointer to the first row of a matrix where each row is an array of 5 integers. &ages = the address where the first member of the array is stored. As mentioned in dbush's answer, since ages is an array of 5 integers, then &ages+1 points to what would be an array of 5 integers after the 5 integers in ages, so + 5 * 4, where 4 is the size of an integer, effectively the same as a pointer to the second row of a matrix where each row is an array of 5 integers.

The example code doesn't print out ages and ages+1, which would differ by sizeof(int) instead of by 5 * sizeof(int). Without the & prefix on ages, the size of the array would not matter.

cur_ages and cur_ages+1 point to the first and second integers in ages, as expected.

*cur_ages and *(cur_ages+1) are the first and second integer values in ages.

Answer (score 2):

Several things are happening here.

1. `&cur_ages` is the address of a pointer to a value, not the address of a value.  Because of the [(arguably odd) semantics of array names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17752978/2877364) in C, `&ages` is the address of a value.
2. Pointer arithmetic (`&<anything>+1`) works by whole items, not by bytes.  Therefore, adding 1 to an `int *` will add `sizeof(int)` bytes, not one byte.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a Terrible answer from the beginner view :) Special with this part `&cur_ages is the address of a pointer to a value, not the address of a value. `