# What is the difference between 'struct (*)[]' and 'struct *[]'?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I am playing around with pointers, arrays of pointers, and arrays.

I created a `struct` called `Fraction` and tried passing an array of `Fraction` into a function that takes an array of `Fraction` pointers.  I get the error:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'void display(Fraction *[],int)' : cannot convert 
                             argument 1 from 'Fraction (*)[10]' to 'Fraction *[]'
```

I understand that this does not work, but what you you call each of these? `Fraction(*)[]` and `Fraction*[]`. for example: int[] is an array of integers, and an int* is an integer pointer. The above code, looks identical to me aside from the parenthesis around the *.

I do not need to fix this error I just simply want to understand the differences between the two, seemingly similar structures.

Comment: how is farry declared ?

Comment: @Christophe Fraction farry[MAX_SIZE]; where max_size is 10

Comment: Additionally, max size is declared as a const int before main

Comment: You have answered your own question, your `farry` should be declared as  `Fraction* farry = new Fraction[MAX_SIZE]` because your function expects a pointer of a pointer and what you are passing is just a pointer to a first element of the array. if you would dereference that farry by using it as `*farry` you would get the first element of the array, if you would declare it as I pointed out you would get a pointer to an array which then points to a first element of an array, simple :-)

Comment: @XAMlMAX Do that and things will be even more wrong than they already are. The function as-written expects a sequence of pointers to objects; not a sequence of objects. No allocation of the form `new Fraction[N]` is going to work with that function, *regardless* of whether you pass the pointer referring to those object by address or not. Worse, doing as you describe and passing `&farry` will completely hide the problem until runtime when *undefined behavior* is invoked.

Comment: @WhozCraig I never said to pass `&farry` to anywhere, I was making a point that the type that he was passing didn't match the argument that was expected by the function. And the function expects a pointer to a pointer if you declare a variable `Fraction** farry` and initialize it properly it would still work for this function.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I understand that. You said, "your `farry` should be declared as `Fraction* farry = new Fraction[MAX_SIZE]` because your function expects a pointer of a pointer and what you are passing is just a pointer to a first element of the array." The OP changing their code to do that, and only that, while retaining their call to `display(&farry, fracCounter);` as described in the question (which the compiler will happily accept), is still wrong, but arguably *worse*, because now the problem won't be caught until runtime (if they're lucky). That was my only point.

Comment: @WhozCraig I see your point now, fair play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Fraction*[]` is an array of `Fraction*` (an array of pointers).  `Fraction(*)[]` is a pointer to `Fraction[]` (pointer to an array).  The difference is that parentheses isolate the "pointer" from the `Fraction`, because otherwise the two would bind to each other and give you a different type than intended.

Mechanically, a `*` or a `&` would much rather bind to a type name than be isolated and represent the entire thing, so you have to use parentheses to isolate it from the element type.  This is also true when declaring function pointers: `int*(int, int)` is a function that takes two `int`s and returns an `int*`, while `int(*)(int, int)` is a pointer to a function that takes two `int`s and returns an `int`.

Consider [this](http://ideone.com/yojSRJ) simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct Type {};

// 1: Array of Type*.
void func(Type *arr [3]) {
    std::cout << "Type* array.\n"
              << typeid(arr).name() << "\n\n";
}

// 2: Array of Type&.
// Illegal.
// void func(Type &arr [3]) {
//     std::cout << "Type& array.\n"
//               << typeid(arr).name() << "\n\n";
// }

// 3: Pointer to array of Type.
void func(Type (*arr) [3]) {
    std::cout << "Pointer to Type array.\n"
              << typeid(arr).name() << "\n\n";
}

// 4: Reference to array of Type.
void func(Type (&arr) [3]) {
    std::cout << "Reference to Type array.\n"
              << typeid(arr).name() << "\n\n";
}

int main() {
    // Array of Type.
    Type   t_arr[3] = {};

    // Array of Type*.
    Type* tp_arr[3] = { &t_arr[0], &t_arr[1], &t_arr[2] };

    // Array of Type&.
    // Illegal.
    // Type& tr_arr[3] = { t_arr[0], t_arr[1], t_arr[2] };

    std::cout << "Type[3]: " << typeid(t_arr).name() << "\n\n";

    func(t_arr);  // Calls #4.
    func(&t_arr); // Calls #3.
    func(tp_arr); // Calls #1.
}
```

Depending on the compiler used, it'll output either mangled or unmangled types for `arr`, and the output shows that all three are different types:

```
// MSVC:
Type[3]: struct Type [3]

Reference to Type array.
struct Type [3]

Pointer to Type array.
struct Type (*)[3]

Type* array.
struct Type * *

// GCC:
Type[3]: A3_4Type

Reference to Type array.
A3_4Type

Pointer to Type array.
PA3_4Type

Type* array.
PP4Type
```

This syntax is a bit wonky if you're not used to it, and can be somewhat easy to mistype, so it may be a good idea to make a type alias if you need to use it.

```
// Array.
typedef Type Type_arr_t[3];

// Pointer.
typedef Type (*Type_arr_ptr_t)[3];

// Reference.
typedef Type (&Type_arr_ref_t)[3];

// ...

// Without typedefs.
Type   arr   [3];
Type (*arr_p)[3] = &arr;
Type (&arr_r)[3] =  arr;

// With typedefs.
Type_arr_t     arr2;
Type_arr_ptr_t arr2_p = &arr2;
Type_arr_ref_t arr2_r =  arr2;
```

This is extremely useful when declaring functions that return pointers or references to arrays, because they look silly without typedefs, and are *really* easy to get wrong and/or forget the syntax for.

```
typedef Type (*Type_arr_ptr_t)[3];
typedef Type (&Type_arr_ref_t)[3];

// Without typedefs.
Type (*return_ptr())[3];
Type (&return_ref())[3];

// With typedefs.
Type_arr_ptr_t return_ptr_2();
Type_arr_ref_t return_ref_2();
```

For more information regarding how to parse something like this, see the [clockwise spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

---

Note: When an array is passed by value as a function parameter, and in many other situations (specifically, in any situation where an array isn't expected, but a pointer is), type and dimension information is lost, and it is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element of the array; this is known as the array [*decaying* into a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying).  This is demonstrated in `func(Type*[3])` above, where the compiler takes a parameter type of `Type*[3]`, an array of `Type*`, and replaces it with `Type**`, a pointer to `Type*`; the `[3]` is lost, and replaced with a simple `*`, because functions can take pointers but not arrays.  When `func()` is called, the array will decay due to this.  Due to this, the following signatures are treated as identical, with the parameter being `Type**` in all three.

```
void func(Type*[3]);
void func(Type*[] ); // Dimension isn't needed, since it'll be replaced anyways.
void func(Type**  );
```

This is done because it's more efficient than trying to pass the entire array by value (it only needs to pass a pointer, which easily fits inside a single register, instead of trying to load the entire thing into memory), and because encoding the array type into the function's parameter list would remove any flexibility from the function regarding the size of the array it can take (if a function were to take `Type[3]`, then you couldn't pass it a `Type[4]` or a `Type[2]`).  Due to this, the compiler will silently replace a `Type[N]` or `Type[]` with a `Type*`, causing the array to decay when passed.  This can be avoided by specifically taking a pointer or reference to the array; while this is as efficient as letting the array decay (the former because it still just passes a pointer, the latter because most compilers implement references with pointers), it loses out on flexibility (which is why it's usually paired with templates, which restore the flexibility, without removing any of the strictness).

```
// Will take any pointer to a Type array, and replace N with the number of elements.
// Compiler will generate a distinct version of `func()` for each unique N.
template<size_t N>
void func(Type (*)[N]);

// Will take any reference to a Type array, and replace N with the number of elements.
// Compiler will generate a distinct version of `func()` for each unique N.
template<size_t N>
void func(Type (&)[N]);
```

Note, however, that C doesn't have the luxury of templates, and thus any code that is intended to work with both languages should either use the C idiom of passing a "size" parameter along with the array, or be written specifically for a certain size of array; the former is more flexible, while the latter is useful if you will *never* need to take an array of any other size.

```
void func1(Type *arr, size_t sz);
void func2(Type (*arr)[3]);
```

Also note that there are situations where an array [won't decay into a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752978/exception-to-array-not-decaying-into-a-pointer).

```
// Example array.
Type arr[3];

// Function parameter.
void func(Type arr[3]);
void func(Type (*arr)[3]);
void func(Type (&arr)[3]);

// Function template parameter.
template<typename T>
void temp(T t);

// Class template parameter.
template<typename T>
struct S { typedef T type; };

// Specialised class template parameter.
template<typename T> struct S2;
template<typename T, size_t Sz>
struct S2<T[Sz]> { typedef T type[Sz]; };

func(arr);           // C: arr decays into Type*.
                     // C++: arr either binds to a Type(&)[3], or decays into Type*.
                     //  If both are available, causes error due to ambiguous function call.
func(&arr);          // C/C++: No decay, &arr is Type(*)[3].
sizeof(arr);         // C/C++: No decay, evaluates to (sizeof(Type) * 3).
alignof(arr);        // C/C++: No decay, evaluates to alignof(Type).
decltype(arr);       // C++: No decay, evaluates to Type[3].
typeid(arr);         // C++: No decay, evaluates to a std::type_info for Type[3].
for (Type& t : arr); // C++: No decay, ranged-based for accepts arrays.
temp(arr);           // C++: arr decays to Type* during function template deduction.
temp<Type[3]>(arr);  // C++: No decay, deduction isn't required.

// For class templates, deduction isn't performed, so array types used as template parameters
//  don't decay.
S<Type[3]>::type;    // C++: No decay, type is Type[3].
S2<Type[3]>::type;   // C++: No decay, type is Type[3].

// String literals are arrays, too.
decltype("Hello.");             // C++: No decay, evaluates to const char[7].
char  c_arr[] = "Hello.";       // C/C++: No decay, c_arr is a local array, of type char[7],
                                //  containing copy of "Hello."
const char* c_ptr   = "Hello."; // C/C++: const char[7] "Hello." is stored in read-only
                                //  memory, and ptr points to it.

// There may be other cases in which arrays don't decay, which I'm currently not aware of.
```

So, in short, while, say, `Type[3]` is an array type, and `Fraction*[5]` is an array type, there are cases where a declaration of the two will be silently replaced with a `Type*` or `Fraction**`, respectively, by the compiler, and where type and dimension information will be lost due to this; this loss is known as array decay or array-to-pointer decay.

Thanks go to [juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661519/juanchopanza) for reminding me to mention array-to-pointer decay.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome.  I also edited in a short section about functions that return pointers or references to arrays, because they look _weird_.

Comment: It is appreciated, the examples helped to fully understand how the * and & work in different scenarios.

Comment: `Fraction*[]` is *not* an array or pointers if it is a function parameter. It is a pointer to pointer. And it is important to get that right in this answer because it is the kind of thing that is confusing OP.

Comment: @juanchopanza It is indeed an array of pointers, it just immediately decays _into_ a pointer-to-a-pointer when used as a parameter.  There's a difference.  That said, not only does the answer very specifically demonstrate that (note the output when `func(Type*[])` is called; `typeid` shows that the array of pointers is treated as a `Type**`), but I'm talking in general (and not specifically about parameters).  The question is about why `Fraction*[]` and `Fraction(*)[10]` are different types, which is what I answered.  I guess I should make a note about array decay, though.

Comment: No, it isn't. It is a function *parameter*. It is the argument that decays when the function gets called. The parameter is pointer to pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza I just said "decays into" because it's shorter than "gets replaced by", and I wasn't sure how long that comment was going to be.

Comment: That said, the way I see it, just because the compiler silently _replaces_ an array declaration with a pointer declaration in cases where arrays aren't expected, that doesn't mean that the array declaration itself _is_ a pointer declaration when used in those cases.  It just means exactly what it says: the compiler knows that an array isn't allowed here, but a pointer is, and thus it _replaces_ the array declaration with a pointer declaration while compiling.  There's a semantic difference, and `T [N]` doesn't mean "array if a variable, or pointer if a parameter".

Comment: To quote [CPPReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function), when determining the type of each function parameter, `If the type is "array of T" or "array of unknown bound of T", it is replaced by the type "pointer to T"`; it doesn't say `If the type is "array of T" or "array of unknown bound of T", it is instead interpreted as the type "pointer to T"`.  This rather explicitly means that `T [N]` itself is _always_ an array type, but will be _replaced_ with a pointer type if it's used where an array isn't allowed.

Comment: As this answer was explaining the difference being `Fraction*[]` and `Fraction(*)[]`, not about explaining why what he did doesn't work, the semantic difference is very important.  If it was explaining why it doesn't work, then clarifying that the parameter itself is a `Fraction**` would be more important.  Hence, forgetting to mention array decay until you reminded me.

Comment: That said, I've added a note about array-to-pointer decay, and when it does and doesn't happen.

Comment: So much talk, but your leading sentence is still wrong. Just fix it already. The thing isn't an array, period.

Comment: Ant "decays to" may be shorted than "is adjusted to", but it also happens to be completely wrong because there is actually a thing called array decay.

Comment: @juanchopanza `Fraction*[]` is an array declaration, no matter what context it's used in.  If specified as a function parameter, however, it is _replaced_ by a `Fraction**` pointer declaration; I both explained and demonstrated this, too.  Just because one is _replaced_ by the other in some contexts, that doesn't mean that it _is_ the other, _especially_ not in a general sense.  And, as I've already said and you apparently ignored, my answer is speaking in general, not specifically about when used as a function parameter.  (And no offense, but I trust CPPReference a lot more than I trust you.)

Comment: Or, in other words: The question was "I understand that this does not work, but I would like to understand what the difference is between `Fraction(*)[]` to `Fraction*[]`."  My answer was exactly that: the difference betwen the two, _in a general sense_.  It demonstrates use as a function parameter, definition, type aliasing, and use as a return type.  Claiming that a `Fraction*[]` is a `Fraction**` would be wrong, because it isn't; saying that when used as a function parameter, it is _replaced_ by a `Fraction**`, which I did in the section on array decay, is correct.

Comment: If it is replaced (the terminology in the standard is "type adjustment") such that it is a pointer to a pointer, then it makes no sense to say it is an array of pointers. It is pointer to pointer, and all the array-ness is lost. You can pass it a simple pointer to a pointer to an object. You could try defining the same function with the two equivalent syntaxes and get a nice multiple definition error. It makes no sense to think of the parameter as an array, because it is adjusted to pointer. But if you want to live in a world of confusion, then go ahead.

Comment: @juanchopanza No offense, but I don't think you understand that my answer _isn't **only** about when it's used as a function parameter_.  See [here](http://ideone.com/lFO5A7).  Note, if you will, that the _only_ time it is replaced by a pointer is when used as a function parameter.  So, no, it _wouldn't_ be correct to say that `Fraction*[]` is actually a `Fraction**`, _because that isn't always true_.  To be correct, the answer needs to explain what the first is, then explain _when_ it's replaced with the other, which is what it does.

Comment: It so happens that the question is about `Fraction*[]` being a function parameter. That is the only thing OP will be thinking of when reading your answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza I know what the question asks, but my answer is intended to be more general, in case someone else is curious about the difference in the future, but in a different context.  The second part, which I added after you reminded me, is intended to describe circumstances in which it'll be replaced by a pointer and the array will decay.

Answer (score 5):

**Cause of the error**

The parameter `Fraction *fracArr[]` expects an array of pointers to fractions.

You have defined `Fraction farry[max_size];` meaning that `farry` is an array of fractions.

When you call the function providing `&farry` as first argument, you are trying to take a pointer to an array (`Fraction (*)[10]`) instead of an array of pointers (`Fraction *[]`).  Therefore the mismatch error.

**Solution**

If your goal is to work with an array of fractions, just change your function as follows:

```
void display(Fraction fracArr[], int fracCounter){
    for (int i = 0; i < fracCounter; i++){
        cout << fracArr[i].num << "/" << fracArr[i].den << endl;
    }
}
```

and call it with `display(farry, fracCounter);`.

**Additional remarks:**

More generally, an argument of type array of unknown size `T arg[]` is passed as a pointer `T *arg` pointing to the first element.

Defining your argument `Fraction *arg[]` or `Fraction **arg` would result in the same code.  The `[]` just hides this technical detail and make the intent clearer (i.e. working with an array of pointers vs. working with a pointer to pointer)

Comment: I also have an array of pointers called fracArray, which was declared, Fraction *fracArray[MAX_SIZE]; I was trying to use the display function for both, more as a means to understand what would happen. @xamimax

Comment: @BrettReinhard So if you add `fracArray[0] = Fraction();` is that still array of pointers?

Comment: I think I confused that an address of an array of fractions would be the same as an arrays of fraction pointers. Would this be a fair assumption to say that they are not viewed the same by the compiler ? @christophe I understand that an array is by definition an address.

Comment: You can't have the same funtion processing either values or pointer to values.  For fracArray it would work as it was, if you just leave the `&` out of the function call (in fact if you define an array,  the name of that array without an indice is the address of that array).  If you want to use the same function name to do different processes depending on the parameter type, you have to consider making an overload.

Comment: I guess that my question more directly should phrased what does this actually mean: Fraction (*)[10]' and what does this mean: 'Fraction *[]'

Comment: "The parameter `Fraction *fracArr[]` is an array of pointers to fractions. " It is actually a pointer to pointer to `Fraction`.

Comment: @BrettReinhard [An outstanding site to answer similar questions](http://cdecl.org/).

Comment: @juanchopanza you are perfectly right: a [] in a function parameter means indeed a pointer.  The equivalent gcc message refers to Fraction** instead of MSVC more polite Fraction*[]. But this doesn't change op's issue and i didn't want to add to the confusion: the main problem is trying to get the adress of an array, and the mismatch in the level of indirection.

Comment: @Christophe Actually, arrays don't _always_ decay to raw pointers when passed as parameters.  Both `Fraction (&arr)[3]` and `Fraction (*arr)[3]` preserve type information, while `Fraction arr[3]` will indeed decay.

Comment: @Christophe It mens your leading sentence is incorrect and misleading. Fortunately it is easy to change!

Comment: @juanchopanza you're right ! Let's clarify with "expects" insead" of "is", and an additional paragraph for additional details on the relation between arrays and pointers.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of these places where the compiler outputting a raw type versus a parameter declaration causes a little confusion.  If you re-insert the variable names, the comparison is now between:

```
Fraction (*farray)[10]
```

and:

```
Fraction *farray[]
```

At this point the error becomes obvious *if you are willing to accept that declarations have a precedence just like regular expressions.*

According to C/C++'s precedence table, `[]` as the array index operator binds more tightly than unary `*` the pointer de-reference operator.

If you apply this same rule to the declarations, the second becomes an array of pointers, while the first one has the "pointer" bound more tightly due to the parentheses, therefore it is a pointer to an array.