# How does the compiler interprets the sizeof() operator performed on an array in C, as the array is actually a constant pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Say I have a code:

```
int a[5];
printf("%d %d %d",sizeof(a));
```

The output is

20

As a is a constant pointer pointing to the integer a[0], shouldn't the sizeof(a) be 4 bytes, instead why is it 20 bytes?

Comment: `As a is a constant pointer pointing to the integer a[0]` It isn't. Its an array.

Comment: An array is decyed to the pointer to its 1st element when being used as argument to a function. `sizeof` is *not* a function. `sizeof` is an operator. So there is *no need* to wrap the variable `a` in parenthesis. `sizeof a` would just do and (in your example) will evaluate to `20`.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and turn on **all** your compiler warnings, and mind them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As a is a constant pointer pointing to the integer a[0], shouldn't the sizeof(a) be 4 bytes, instead why is it 20 bytes?

Wording is important. As stated in the comments, `a` isn't a pointer, its an array.

`a` *gets converted* to a pointer to its first element in *most* cases, [but not all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17752978/3049655). One such exception is when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator. So the `sizeof` will be similar to `sizeof(int[5])` (and not `sizeof(int*)` as you expected) which returns `5 * sizeof(int)`. The result, as you can see, will most likely be `20` as `sizeof(int)` is 4 on most systems.

---

*Side note:* I assume you meant `printf("%d", sizeof(a));` instead of using three format specifiers. And you should be using `%zu` there as `sizeof` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a array so there are 5 elements as 0,1,2,3,4 so one element is 4 bytes then 5 elements should be 20 bytes.
you can get sizeOf as

`printf("%d", sizeof(a));`