# Array gets modified not int when called in a function

Tags: c, arrays, function

When I run this program-

```
#include <stdio.h>
void inc( int num[], int n)
{
  int i;
  n++;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    num[i]++;
}

int main()
{
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
  int a=2;
  inc (arr, a);
  int i; 
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    printf("%d  ", arr[i]); 
  printf("\n%d  ", a);
return 0;
}
```

I get the output-

```
2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  1                                                                                                                  
2
```

I understand why the int is unchanged but I don't understand why the array is getting changed since I have not used pointers to call the array. I know that the function will make a different copy of n and assign n=a and all changes will happen to n only and a will be unchanged. Why the array is getting changed?

Comment: The array *degrades to* a pointer when used like this. It is not (and can not) be copied during the function call.

Comment: Functionally `void inc( int num[], int n)`  is the same as `void inc( int *num, int n)`

Comment: When you pass an array to a function, you are using pointers, whether you know it or not.

Comment: *I know that the function will make a different copy [...]* – the 2nd parameter will be copied, yes. But arrays don't have copy semantic in C and C++. Just try `int foo[5]; int bar[5]; foo = bar;`

Comment: you are passing array pointer not array in calling inc(arr, n)

Answer (score 0):

In C, except for a [**few cases**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752978/exceptions-to-array-decaying-into-a-pointer), an array name decays (=gets implicitly converted) to a pointer to its first element.

This

```
void inc(int num[], int n)
```

is exactly same as this:

```
void inc(int *num, int n)
```

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)