# Accessing Array Element

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int arr[]= {5,15,1,3,4};

    // Since we know arr and &arr are both address of first element of array.
    // I read somewhere that &arr+1 = baseaddress + sizeof(arr).
    // arr+1 = address of second element
    // am curious to know the diff. between two semantics.
printf("%d %d\n",*(arr+1), *(&arr+1));
```

I know it's trivial, but am curious to clear the concept.

Comment: Read [Inconsistency in using pointer to an array and address of an array directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661078/inconsistency-in-using-pointer-to-an-array-and-address-of-an-array-directly/17663091#17663091)

Comment: `*(&arr+1)` undefined behavior, I explained. And you can to read [What does `sizeof(&array)` return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarray-return/15177499#15177499) to understand difference between `(arr+1)`, and `(&arr+1)`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: +1 It's a dupe

Comment: @neham Read updated answer I linked, I added some more information.

Answer (score 2):

`arr` is of type array and `&arr` is of type pointer (array). Their types are not the same.

This `&arr+1` is pointer arithmetic. Increasing the `&arr` by 1 will take you to last position + 1 in the array. Example:

```
   |0|1|2|3|4| |
 arr^         ^
        &arr+1^
```

Comment: [tool to draw asii charts](http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw)

Comment: &arr+1 might not show the location that is depicted at the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `arr` is `int[4]` that decays into address of first element in expression `arr + 1`, adding one  results points to second element in `arr`; whereas type of `&arr` is `int(*)[4]` and adding one to `&arr` make it points to next array that is actually not exist hence dereferences `*(&arr+1)`  undefined behavior at runtime.  Consider diagram below:

```
              +---------------+
              |       5       | --+   arr[0]
              |---------------|   |
 arr + 1 ---> |       15      |   |   arr[1]
              +---------------+   |
              |       1       |   |   arr[2]
              +---------------+   |
              |       3       |   |   arr[3]
              +---------------+   |
              |       4       | --+   arr[4]
              +---------------+
              |   Random      |
&arr + 1 ---->|   Memory      |
              +---------------+
              |               |
              +---------------+
```

`*(arr+1)` dereferences the second element of arr and  `*(&arr+1)` dereferences  random memory

Comment: Add this before diagram: "Type of `arr` is `int[4]` that decays into first elements's address and hence `arr + 1` points to second element, whereas  type of `&arr` is `int(*)[4]`. and adding one to `&arr` make it points to next array that is actually not exist hence `*(&arr+1)` dereferences - undefined behaviour"

Answer (score 1):

`arr` is array not the address of first element. It decays to pointer to first element of the array `arr`. `&arr` is address of the entire memory block containing the array `arr`.
In

```
printf("%d %d\n",*(arr+1), *(&arr+1));
```

`*(arr+1)` dereference the second element of array `arr` (you would get `15` but undefined behavior is invoked so nothing can be said here) while 
`*(&arr+1)` will invoke undefined behavior. This is because you are dereferencing an entire block of array past the array `arr` (out side the allocated memory).

Comment: Actually `*(&arr+1)` try to dereferencing  outside allocated memory as `&arr + 1` is addressing outside array.

Comment: That's what I added in my last statement `past the array `arr`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; Also added your line :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int arr[5] = {5,15,1,3,4}; //arr is an array of 5 ints

  //arrays are just pointers to their first value
  printf("the value of arr: %p\n", arr); 
  //this should be the same as arr, since arr is just a pointer to its first value
  printf("the locate of arr[0]: %p\n", &arr[0]);

  //arr+1 is just pointer arithmetic. So arr+1 should be a pointer to the second element in arr.
  printf("When we dereference the pointer to the second element in arr, we should get that number: %d\n", *(arr+1));

  //Since arr is a pointer to the first element in an array, address-of'ing it gives us the address of that pointer in memory.
  printf("*(&arr+1): %p\n", *(&arr+1));
  //Adding 1 to the address of a pointer just gives us a higher address that points to nothing in particular (some place on the stack)
}

/*
 * Output:
 * the value of arr: 0x7ffff2681820
 * the locate of arr[0]: 0x7ffff2681820
 * When we dereference the pointer to the second element in arr, we should get that number: 15
 * *(&arr+1): 0x7ffff2681834
 */
```

Edit:
  By adding prints for the other 4 memory addresses we can see that *(&addr+1) points to the location right after the fifth element in the array.

```
 arr+1: 0x7fff38560224

 arr+2: 0x7fff38560228

 arr+3: 0x7fff3856022c

 arr+4: 0x7fff38560230
```