# Pointer to array Vs normal pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am bit confused with respect to pointer to arrays and just normal pointer and how to access.
I have tried this...

```
int *ptr1, i;
int (*ptr2)[3];
int myArray[3] = {1, 1, 1};
int myArray1[5] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
ptr1 = myArray;
ptr2 = myArray1;// compiles fine even though myArray1 contains 5 elements 
                 // and ptr2 is pointing to array of 3 elements.

printf("%d",ptr2[3]); // prints some garbage.
```

Why this statement is printing garbage? What is the correct statement?
Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can also declare pointer to array as

```
int (*ptr)[]; // ptr is a pointer to array.
```

When you do

```
ptr2 = myArray1;
```

compiler will throw you a warning message. `Look boss types are not compatible.`
In some context Arrays decays into pointers. Warning message is because, when arrays decays into pointers, the decayed type is pointer. In this case, when you do

```
ptr1 = myArray;
```

myArray decays into `int *`.

But when you do,

```
ptr2 = myArray1;
```

`myArray1` decays into pointer that is `int *`, but the type of `ptr2` is `int (*)[]`.

In order to avoid warning, you should say

```
ptr2 = &myArray1; //&myArray1 returns address of array and type is int(*)[].
```

**Why this statement is printing garbage? What is the correct statement? Can anyone explain?**

```
printf("%d",ptr2[3]);// prints some garbage.
```

Yes, But why? Lets see the correct statement first...(note that index should be less than 3)

```
printf("myArray1[%d] = %d\n", i, (*ptr2)[2]);
```

We have to use `(*ptr2)[i]` to print the array element. This is because, just by mentioning `ptr2`, we will get the address of the array (not the address of some `int`). and by de-referencing it `(*ptr2)` we will get the address of `0th element` of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer `ptr2` is pointer to int array of size three

```
ptr2 = myArray1;  // you may getting warning for this
```

should be:

```
ptr2 = &myArray1; // use & operator
```

And

```
printf("%d", ptr2[3]);
```

should be:

```
printf("%d", (*ptr2)[2]); // index can't be 3 for three size array 
 //          ^^^^^^^
```

Notice parenthesis around `*ptr2` is needed as precedence of `[]` operator is higher then `*`  dereference  operator (whereas if you use pointer to int you don't need parentheses as in above code).

Read [Inconsistency in using pointer to an array and address of an array directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661078/inconsistency-in-using-pointer-to-an-array-and-address-of-an-array-directly) I have explained both array to access array elements. (1) Using pointer to int (2) pointer to array

Whereas `ptr1 = myArray;` is just find, you can simply access array elements using `ptr1[i]` (not `i` values should be  0 to 4)

Answer (score 1):

```
int (*ptr2)[3];
```

This signifies that `(*ptr2)` is the identifier which contains the location in memory of the beginning of an integer array. Or, rephrasing, that `ptr2` is an address. That address contains a value. That value is itself the address of the beginning of an array of ints.

So when you write `ptr2 = myArray1` you are basically saying "The address of my address holder is the address of the beginning of `myArray1`".

So when you go to print the value using `ptr2[3]` you are actually printing the value of the *memory address* of `myArray1`, incremented `3*sizeof(ptr2)` units. Which is why it looks like garbage, it's some memory address.

What should be in the print statement is `(*ptr2)[3]` which means "Take the address of `ptr2` and get the value stored at that address. Next, using that second address, increment it `3*sizeof(int)` and get the value stored at that incremented address."

Arrays in C are nothing more than a contiguous region of allocated memory. Which is why saying:

```
int *x = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
```

Is the same as:

```
int x[3];
```

Since `[]` and `*` both dereference a pointer, if we wanted to access the second element of either array, we could write:

```
int value = x[1];
```

or

```
int value = *x+sizeof(int); // Since *x would be index 0
```

Two of the major differences are that the `[]` notation is a bit easier to read but lengths must be  determined at compile time. Whereas, with the `*x`/`malloc()` notation, we can dynamically create an array or arbitrary length.

Comment: "int *x = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
Is the same as:

int x[3];" No it isn't. One is a pointer. One is an array. They are very different.