# why in array a[] , &a and a are the same?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2];
    int *b=&a;
    printf("%p\n",a);
    printf("%p\n",&a);
    printf("%p",b);
    return 0;
}
```

All printing same things!! `a` is a pointer to first place of our array right?! It must be saved somewhere!! so `&a` or `b` must be a pointer to `a`...

I'm wrong?!

BTW ive got a warning from my compiler about `int *b=&a;`

```
[Warning] initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

Comment: Read [Difference between `&str` and `str`, when `str` is declared as `char str[10]`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarray-return/15177499#15177499)

Comment: And I think I have answer your question here [Inconsistency in using pointer to an array and address of an array directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661078/inconsistency-in-using-pointer-to-an-array-and-address-of-an-array-directly/17663091#17663091) It is kind of duplicate.

Comment: You missed `&a[0]` :D

Comment: @anishsane he didn't miss `[0]` but OP thinks that `&a` is address of first element...Read title of question he is asking `a` and `&a` are same??

Comment: I meant, typically, people ask differences between `a`, `&a` & `&a[0]`... OP asked only 2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

&a is `int (*)[2]`. i.e pointer to an array.

But `int *b=&a;` assigns to integer pointer. Though it points to proper address, you need to typecast to remove the warning message.

Add `(int*)` like.

```
int *b=(int*)&a;

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2] = {10,20};
    int *b=(int*)&a;

    printf("\n :%d   %d\n", b[0], b[1]);
#if 0
    printf("%p\n",a);
    printf("%p\n",&a);
    printf("%p",b);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

prints 10 and 20.

Comment: Your cast is incorrect. To get valid code you must either use a valid pointer or point `b` to `a`, not `&a`.

Comment: just `int *b = a`  is enough either use `int *b = &a[0]`

Comment: Remove the cast *and* the ampersand. `int *b = a;`

Comment: waning message is removed. May be best is using proper pointer. But why cast is wrong here !!!!!

Comment: @self. why cast is incorrect? it is not wrong.

Comment: The code will ( probably always )work, but that doesn't mean it is correct.

Comment: @self. it is not the way we do but it is correct and cast is correct.

Comment: ty, but still i cant understand why b and a value's are equal. b is a pointer to a and a is a pointer to a[0] or something else?!

Comment: The cast is not necessary, you could use this definition of `b`: `int (*b)[2]=&a;`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Why use a forced cast to fix an incorrect assign, when you can do things correctly??!

Comment: @self, this casting is common in such cases like handling a large buffer using a pointer. There is no wrong in that.

Comment: @amfad33 Read answers I linked `a` is of type `int[2]` that decays int o `int*` when assigned to `b`.  And `&a` is address of array not first element. to assigned address of array you need to declare b as `int (*b)[2] = &a;`

Comment: @self. yes your argument is correct. And it is not correct approach.

Comment: oh! i got that answer ty; :)