# sizeof() function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
main()
{
char a[] = "Visual C++";
char *b = "Visual C++";
printf("\n %d %d",sizeof(a),sizeof(b));
printf("\n %d %d",sizeof(*a),sizeof(*b));
}
```

`sizeof(a)` gives me output: `11`  ( that is length of the string)

Why is it so ?
Why isn't the output `sizeof(a)`=`4` since when I try to print `a` it gives me an address value and hence an integer?

Comment: Read: [What does sizeof(&arr) return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-return/15177499#15177499) given a answer with diagrams and working codes

Comment: And, just to be picky, `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: @shivaji_vidhale: "why is it so, why isn't the output sizeof(a)=4 since when I try to print a it gives me an address value and hence an integer." A dollar says if you print it by using `puts(a)`, it doesn't "give you an address value".

Comment: Also, `%d` is not the correct format specifier for `size_t` (the type what `sizeof` yields). What you are looking for is `%zu`.

Comment: I dont want to print a. Just want to know why doesn't sizeof(a) give the size of an integer. Since when I try to print a i get an address.

Comment: @Shivaji_Vidhale Because `a` is not an integer, in first place?

Comment: @Shivaji_Vidhale: "Since when I try to print a i get an address." One more time, you only get an address when you tell it to print an address. Just don't tell it to do that, and your confusion will go away.

Comment: Consider this : `char a[10];` what do you think `sizeof(a)` evaluates to .... its `10*size of the a[0]` in this case ( I mean the array not allocated through malloc) its an exception to the   normal result of `sizeof`. In case of arrays the array names decay to pointer.

Comment: @PHIfounder What do you mean by "it's an exception"? What would be the "normal result"?

Comment: @H2CO3 Exception means using the array names in `sizeof`.... normally it would result in the size of the datatype e.g, `char` `int` or pointers

Comment: @PHIfounder I don't think so. `sizeof()` always yields the size of its argument. There's no exception.

Comment: @H2CO3 In case of arrays it yields the size of the whole array .That's an exception . Normally it yields the size of the datatype whatever it may be .

Comment: @PHIfounder: "normally it would result in the size of the datatype" - the size of the datatype `char[11]` *is* 11, this is not an exception.

Comment: @PHIfounder I still don't see why it is an exception. If an array is passed to `sizeof()`, it yields the size of the array. If any other object of type `T` is passed to it, then it gives back the size of `T`.

Comment: @H2CO3 OK I was writing it wrong ,I meant that the array name decays to pointer to the first element of the array that is `a[0]` but here sizeof yields the whole array size . What Paul griffiths says is right but I didn't mean that .

Comment: It only decays, or implicitly converts, when there is something it needs to convert to. `puts()`, for instance, is explicitly defined as taking an argument of type `const char *`, so the array implicitly decays to one. `char * b = a;` is even more explicit. But the `sizeof` operator will accept the plain array, so no implicit conversion needs to, or does, happen. It's not that `sizeof` makes an exception, rather that it does not provide any conditions in which an implicit conversion needs to take place, just like if you defined a function `void myfunc(char a[11]) {};`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: That is not an accurate description of the semantics. There is an explicit exception for `sizeof`. C 2011 6.3.2.1 3: “Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil: +1 for quoting from the standard, and fair play. I'd still say that matches "`sizeof` ... does not provide any conditions in which an implicit conversion needs to take place", although I stand corrected that it can implicitly convert in the absence of something that requires it.

Comment: And, for @PHIfounder's benefit, the "exception" is to the general rule that expressions of type "array of type" convert to expressions of type "pointer to type", not an exception to how the `sizeof` operator functions. `sizeof` does get an expression of type "array of type", it doesn't get an expression of type "pointer to type" and then makes an exception to treat it differently from other expressions.

Comment: @Shivaji_Vidhale You can start with Pointers in C by Yashwant Kanetkar.

Answer (score 10):

Whenever you refer to the name of the array in your program, It normally decays to a pointer to the first element of the array. One of the exception to this rule is the `sizeof` operator. So when you consider the following code.

```
int main()
{
   char a[] = "Visual C++";
   printf("sizeof(a)=%d\n",sizeof(a)); /* Here sizeof(a) indicates sizeof array */
   printf("a=%p",a); /* Here the array name, passed as an argument to printf decays into a pointer of type (char *) */
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the accuracy (or the English semantics) of "a refers to the pointer", but it is certainly true that a pointer to the first element of `a` is passed as the second argument to `printf`.

Comment: To expand on that: the correct terminology to use would be "the array decays into a pointer" or it is "implicitly converted to a pointer".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.Improved the comment.

Comment: Yes type of `a` is `char[N]` and type of pointer is `char*` (type of `b`), but in most operations `char[N]` decays into `char*` but not with `sizeof()`.

Answer (score 3):

In the declaration `char a[] = "Visual C++"`, `a` is an array of 11 `char`. So its size is 11 bytes.

In the declaration `char *b = "Visual C++"`, `b` is a pointer to `char`. So its size is four bytes (in the C implementation you are using).

In the expression `printf("%s", a)`, `a` is also an array. However, it is automatically converted to a pointer to the first element of the array. So a pointer to `char` is passed to `printf`.

This conversion happens automatically unless an array is the argument of `&`, `sizeof`, or `_Alignof` or is a string literal used to initialize an array of `char`. Because it happens automatically, people tend to think of array names as pointers. However, they are not.

Incidentally, `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

When sizeof is applied to the name of a static array (not an array allocated through malloc), the result is the size in bytes of the whole array. This is one of the few exceptions to the rule that the name of an array is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array, and is possible just because the actual array size is fixed and known at compile time, when sizeof operator is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of errors, here.

"`sizeof(a)` gives me output: `11` (length of the string)"

The length of the string is `10`, not `11`. `sizeof(a)` gives you the length of the array.

"why is it so, why isn't the output `sizeof(a)`=`4` since when I try to print `a` it gives me an address value"

Here are two methods of "printing `a`" which do not "give you an address value":

```
puts(a);
```

and:

```
printf("%s\n", a);
```

so your logic is flawed, and this is the source of your confusion. "Printing `a`" only "gives you an address value" when you explicitly or implicitly elect to do so.

`sizeof(a)` gives 11 in this case because the C language defines the `sizeof` operator to give you the size of an array when an array is the operand. This, I'd argue, is the most natural behavior people would expect, so presumably that's why it is defined as such.

"and hence an integer."

In any case, an address is an address, not an integer. At best you could argue that it ought to give you the size of a pointer, but certainly not the size of an integer.

Comment: "But hey, the size of an integer is 4 bytes, and the size of a pointer is 4 bytes too, and anyways, pointers are just integers!" (Better make this comment before OP does so.)