# Function returning a pointer to an int array

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers

I am learning C++ from Primer 5th edition and I am at Returning a Pointer to an Array. The declaration of this function is:

```
 int (*func(int i))[10];
```

and it's expected to return a pointer to an array.

I wrote code that does this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int *func(){
  static int a[]={1,2,3};
  return a;
}
int main (){
  int *p=func();
  for(int i=0;i!=3;++i){
    cout<<*(p+i);
  }
}
```

And it is working. But I want to know the difference between what I made here and

```
  int (*func(int i))[10];
```

How I can make this function call work, because in the book, there isn't any concrete example.

Comment: Yes because i don t understand this type of function and i made this code, and working but i want to work int (*func(int i))[10];

Comment: I think you are confuse between [array name = `a` , `int*`and address of array `&a`, `int(*)[5]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-return/15177499#15177499) read lined answer may help you.

Comment: @jrok: This question seems better than the other, I don't know why the votes to close, as it is well formed (well, on the average of the quality of the site I'd say)

Comment: you are returning address of first element. Actually type of `a` is `int[3]` that decays into `int*`. Important is    
you stores address into `int* p` and can assess elements of array as `p[i]`. Whereas if your function would be `int (*func(int i))[3]` then you return `&a` and assign to `int(*p)[3]` and can access `(*p)[i]`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yeah, I feel a bit bad now :) voting to reopen.

Comment: Can you explicitly state the difference? I don't see it.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan thank you very much, but for 20 minutes i reading and rereading your comment and i can t understand. Can you make  like a code who working, because I can t understand where comes every declaration .

Comment: @alin let me know does my answer helps, ask your doubt to my answer.. feel free to ask ..

Comment: @alin In you previous question [you got the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17871039/1673391) that no buddy notice, and voted.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Thank you very much for your answer, it helped me and i understan in finally, but i have one more question, how i escape by static int a[]{}, so, I want to return a array not from fuction, by exemple from int main(), or anywere

Comment: @alin (1) comment to answer instead to your question (else it will confuse other). (2) I couldn't understand your question --but Understand if you declares your array simply `int a[] = {1, 3, 3}` instead of using `static` keyword then is becomes buggy code. because life & scope of local array is till function not returns.

Comment: yes i know that if i don t use static it is wrong, it says this in book and i understand this, but i want to know if is any possibilities to return other array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34242/discussion-between-alin-and-grijesh-chauhan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read: [What does sizeof(&array) return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-return/15177499#15177499)  to understand diffrence between `array name` and `address of array`.

> **Q1** I want to know the difference between:

In your code:

```
  int *func(){
    static int a[]={1,2,3};
    return a;
  }
```

you are returning address of first element. Actually type of `a` is `int[3]` that decays into `int*`. Important is
You stores address into `int* p` and can assess elements of array as `p[i]`.

Whereas if your function would be int `int (*func())[3]` then you return `&a`,  and assign to `int(*p)[3]` and can access `(*p)[i]`.
Note: type of `&a` is `int(*)[3]`.

> **Q2** How i can make this function call work, because in the book, there isn't any concrete example.

like:

```
int (*func())[3]{
    static int a[]={1,2,3};
    return &a;
}
```

And main():

```
int main(){ 
 int i=0;    
 int(*p)[3] = func();
 for(i=0; i<3; i++)
   printf(" %d\n", (*p)[i]);
 return 0;
}
```

You can check second version of code working id [Ideone](http://ideone.com/7gGQfw)

> **Q1** I want to know the difference between:

As you are interested to know diffrence between two so now compare two different declarations of `p` in two versions of code:

**1) :**  `int* p;` and we access array elements as `p[i]` that is equals to `*(p + i)`.

**2) :** `int (*p)[i]` and we access array elements as `(*p)[i]` that is equals to `*((*p) + i)` or just = `*(*p + i)`. ( I added `()` around `*p` to access array element because precedence of `[]` operator is higher then `*` So simple `*p[i]` means defense to the array elements).

**Edit:**

An addition information other then return type:

In both kind of functions we returns address that is of a static variable (array), and a static object life is till program not terminates. So access the array outsize `func()` is not a problem.

Consider if you returns address of simple array (or variable) that is not static (and dynamically allocated) then it introduce as Undefined behavior in your code that can crash.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it helped me and i understan in finally, but i have one more question, how i escape by static int a[]{}, so, I want to return a array not from fuction, by exemple from int main(), or anywere

Comment: @alin see `main()` is quit different function then other its declaration is predefined you can't make a `main()` that returns pointer to array. Its return type has to be int only.

Comment: Sorry @ Grijesh chauhan, but when I "discover" this function (accept an answer)  I give accept at all, and first was your answer, and when i accept any answer your answer was unaccepted. Sorry , i accept your answer.

Comment: @alin Ok no problem, You can vote all, but can accept only one that the reason ?I give a like to you.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan i was reading your answer then i wanted to try your second and third code but i could not compile it (it tells me that Returning 'int[3] *' from a function/method/block returning 'int[3]': Array is not assignabel )

Answer (score 2):

`int(*)[10]` is a pointer to an array of 10 `int`s. `int*` is a pointer to `int`. These are different types.

However, an array *decays* to a pointer to its first element, so you can do:

```
int a[10];
int(*p)[10] = &a;
int* q = a; // decay of int[10] to int*
```

But not:

```
q = p;
p = q;
```