# C++ return pointer to dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am reading this post [[Function returning a pointer to an int array]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882070/function-returning-a-pointer-to-an-int-array) and learning the difference between returning a `pointer to int` and a `pointer to an array of int`. 
 
I got a few questions while trying to sum it up. First, take a look at this code (keeping it simple): 
Functions `test` and `test2` return `pointer to int` and a `pointer to an array of int`

```
int* test(size_t &sz) {
    int *out = new int[5];
    sz = 5;
    return out;
}

int (*test2())[3] {
    static int out[] = {1, 2, 3};
    return &out;
}
```

How do I have to change `test2` to work with dynamic array (not static)? And is it possible to pass an array size as a reference or somehow? 
Main function looks as this. The code compiles.

```
int main() {
    size_t sz;
    int *array = test(sz);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != sz; ++i) {
        array[i] = 10;
        cout << *(array + i) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;    
    delete[] array;

    int (*array2)[3] = test2();
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 3; ++i) {
        cout << (*array2)[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Result

```
10 10 10 10 10 
1 2 3
```

Comment: Why even bother with dynamically allocated arrays? What about `std::vector`?

Comment: Also, if you mean `return &out;` with your question title, then remember that `static` is the opposite of `dynamic`

Comment: I‘am not a compiler, but test2 doesn’t compile in my head.

Comment: It does compile. I can't get it with dynamic array though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test2` does not return a pointer to a single `int`, but a pointer to a 3-element `int` array. I encourage you to try the wonderful https://cdecl.org/ website, enter `int (*test2())[3]` and see for yourself.

You probably tried to return `new int[3]` and it failed. That's because `new[]` returns a pointer to a single `int` (the first element of the dynamically allocated array), and a pointer to a single `int` is not automatically converted to a pointer to an entire array of many `int`s.

> How do I have to change `test2` to work with dynamic array (not static)?

*Strictly technically* speaking, like this:

```
int (*test2())[3] {
    return reinterpret_cast<int(*)[3]>(new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 }); // horrible code
}
```

> And is it possible to pass an array size as a reference or somehow?

In the case of `test2`, the array's size is part of the type and thus fixed at compile time. You cannot change a type at runtime by passing a reference.

---

Now, seriously.

Nobody right in their mind writes code like this. `new[]` is already quite a broken language feature, and your extra obfuscation work with additional pointers, references and C syntax idiosyncrasies doesn't make it better. This is C++, **use `std::vector`**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> test() {
    return { 1, 2, 3 };
}

int main() {
    for (auto num : test()) {
        std::cout << num << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: @ChistianHackl, fantastic answer, special thanks for 'cdecl.org' website