# What is the difference in C between &i and i if i is an array of integers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-address

I tried a code to see what is the difference between `&i` and `i` if `i` is an array. My assumption was that `i` represents the starting address of the array, and I had no idea what will happen if I print `&i` as well.
The result was surprising (to me), as both `i` and `&i` was the starting address of the array.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[25] = "IndiaBIX";

    int i[] = {1,2,3,4};

    printf("%i\n", &i);
    printf("%i\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

The result will be:

```
2686692  
2686692
```

This is the same address.

But if I use a pointer to int:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *j = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *j = 12;

    printf("%i %i %i\n", *j,j,&j);
    return 0;
}
```

The result will be:

```
12
5582744
2686748
```

Here I assume the first is the value of the memory area pointed to by `j`,the second is the address of the memory area pointed to by `j`, the third is the memory address of the pointer itself. If I print `i` and `&i`, why does `&i` not mean the memory address of the pointer `i`?

Comment: I explained: [What does sizeof(&arr) return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-return/15177499#15177499) Check.

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, both i and &i leads to print the same answer but they are not exactly same,

-> i represents the address of the first element in an array named i.

-> &i represents the address of the whole array(though values of both are same, their types are different)

For more info, please refer this [link]http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/arrays_and_address_of.html

```
                    int ar[10];
                    ip = ar;                /* address of first element */
                    ip = &ar[0];            /* address of first element */
                    ar10i = &ar;            /* address of whole array */
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int i[] = {1,2,3,4};
```

The difference is their type, `i` has a type of integer array, `&i` has a type of a pointer of an integer array.