# Size of pointer variable in a structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure, sizeof

```
int main()
{
    struct
    {
        char *name_pointer;
        char all[13];
        int foo;
    } record;

    printf("%d\n",sizeof(record.all));
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(record.foo));
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(record));

    return 0;
}
```

I want the size of the pointer vatiable "*name_pointer" in the structure....

Comment: read: [What does `sizeof(&arr)` return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-return/15177499#15177499) to know differences between `name_pointer` and `all`.

Comment: sizof(char*); would tell you

Comment: sizeof(record.name_pointer);

Comment: you want `sizeof(record.name_pointer)` or `strlen(record.name_pointer)` ?

Comment: what stopped you from sizeof(record.name_pointer);

Answer (score 7):

To get the size of the pointer use

```
printf("%d\n", (int) sizeof(record.name_pointer));
```

Your might get 2, 4, 6, 8, etc.

---

To get the size of the data that is pointed to by the pointer (a `char`) use

```
printf("%d\n", (int) sizeof(*record.name_pointer));
```

Your should get 1.

---

To get the string length of the string pointed to by the pointer, assuming `record.name_pointer` points to legitimate data, use

```
printf("%d\n", (int) strlen(record.name_pointer));
```

---

BTW As @alk says and why the `(int)` casting above, a suitable conversion specifier to use with `sizeof()` includes the 'z' prefix.  The result of `sizeof()` and `strlen()` is of type `size_t`.  Although `size_t` and `int` are often the same, there are many systems where they are of different sizes.  And since sizeof() is an "unsigned integer type" (C11 6.5.3.4), I recommend

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(...
```

Comment: in the second one - data being pointed is a string - not the first character. so this is wrong.

Comment: Nitpick: As `strlen()` returns `size_t` the suitable conversion specifier should be prefixed by the appropriate length modifier `z` to become `zd`.

Comment: @ManojAwasthi: `name_pointer` is defined as `char *`, so it points to exactly **one** character. So everything is fine.

Comment: @alk Yes - I concur - thought of that but was uncertain to add that improvement to a basic question.

Comment: @Manoj Awasthi  `record.name_pointer` is a pointer to a `char`, thus the sizeof(*record.name_pointer) will be **1**.  As a string in C is a variable length array of characters and the string value is passed about by the address of the first `char`, whether `record.name_pointer` is _used_ to point to only 1 `char`, a string, or a fixed char array is indistinguishable from OP's code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer variable will always(32 bit system architecture) have size 4.
if you have 64 bit system architecture it is 8.

Comment: remove *`always`* add *`in your system`*

Comment: Not on 64 bit systems. It's 8 there. And there are others ...!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a GOOD idea to use data types in sizeof rather than variables for native data types. so use:

```
sizeof(char *)
```

Comment: Really? I prefer to use the variable, so code usually remains correct if you change the variable type.

Answer (score -1):

use the following code:

```
printf("%d\n", (int) sizeof(record->name_pointer)/4);
```

Comment: It would be more helpful to provide an explanation along with a working solution.

Comment: This won't work. `record` isn't a pointer so you can't dereference it with `->`. In addition, why are you dividing by 4?