# Trouble with output in c

Tags: c, output

`ptr` can be assumed to have the address `1000:2000`

**code:**

```
int ptr[2];
printf("%p %p %p",&ptr+1,ptr+1,ptr);
```

What will be the output of above code?

**What I tried:**
As I don't know how to interpret/convert `1000:2000` into an address, I tried manually.

I tried this by considering `ptr`'s address as `10000+2000=12000`
So, `&ptr=12000` and `&ptr+1=12000+sizeof(int)`
`ptr` is the address of first element being pointed, similarly `ptr+1` is the second element's address
Is this right?
How can I test this?

Comment: "How to test this?" - how about running it?

Comment: the second and the third parameters should be 0 as they are initialized to 0. the first should just be the address of the first item in the array + 1

Comment: @NoIdeaForName ptr is an array

Comment: @boxed__l yeah... an array is a pointer in c++ my friend

Comment: There's nothing special about that specific address. Run the program, see the result, and deduce what the result is in general.

Comment: What is `1000:2000`? Are you really working under DOS/Real Mode?

Comment: I found this in a textbook, no mention of DOS/Real mode anywhere...and no answer

Comment: @NoIdeaForName No one talked about C++ till now...

Comment: read: [What does sizeof(&arr) return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-return/15177499#15177499)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+-------------------------------------+
|{ ptr[0]  ptr[1] } {ptr1[0],ptr1[1]} |
|   ^      ^           ^              |
|   |      |           |              |
|  ptr   ptr+1         |              |
|   |                  |              |
|  &ptr              &ptr+1           |
+-------------------------------------+
```

It is easy to understand `ptr` pointer the first address item of this array, `ptr+1` pointer the second item of array. `&ptr` ,it is a pointer point a  `int array[2]`  int is a `int (*x)[2]` ,so &ptr +1 means the address move a `int array[2]`.

Here is a test code:

```
  #include <stdio.h> 
  int main()
  {
      int ptr[2];
      int  i;
      for (i =0; i <3; ++i)
          printf("ptr + %d is :   %p\n",i,&(ptr[i])); 
      printf("\n&ptr +1 :    %p\nptr+1  :    %p\nptr  :    %p\n",&ptr+1,ptr+1,ptr);
  }
```

Screen Print

```
ptr + 0 is :    0xbf892614         <---the same as ptr        base address   
ptr + 1 is :    0xbf892618         <---the same as prt+1      4 byte add
ptr + 2 is :    0xbf89261c         < --the same as &ptr +1    4 byte add

&prt +1    :    0xbf89261c      
ptr+1      :    0xbf892618     
ptr        :    0xbf892614
```

Comment: Accepted because "A picture is worth a thousand words"

Answer (score 1):

This is simple pointer arithmetics if you know the types.

```
int ptr[2];
printf("%p %p %p",&ptr+1,ptr+1,ptr);
```

`ptr` is the array's name which decays to a pointer to the first element. Let it be `1000:2000`, if it was an old book.

So `ptr+1` is one element further, thus, if `int` has size 4, `1000:2004`. (Probably `int` has size 2 in this book, so it would be `1000:2002`.)

`&ptr`, however, is a pointer to the array. It points to the same place - `1000:2000` -, but to a larger item: twice as large. So adding 1, the result is incremented by the size of two integers, thus 8 resp 4. So `&ptr+1` gets you `1000:2008` resp. `1000:2004` as answer.

Comment: ptr is assumed to be 1000:2000 => address of ptr or address being pointed to by ptr?

Comment: @boxed__l Both of them. `ptr` is not a pointer, but an array. So `ptr` and `&ptr` point to the same place, but have different types.

Comment: doubt, in Assembly language or something don't we add the addresses like i did to get the actual memory address?? pls expain

Comment: @boxed__l I don't know exactly what you mean. Do you mean the transformation of `Segment:Offset` to `Segment*10+Offset`? That is what I meant with DOS/Real Mode. Nowadays on a PC the addresses are mere 32 or 64 bit numbers.