# Replacing characters in C++ Pointer Character string?

Tags: c++, pointers

Suppose I have this in C++:

```
char *p = "Apple";
```

I can't do this:

```
p[1] = 'w';
```

But why can I do this?

```
p = "OrangeTorange";
```

Comment: There is about 100 of these on here already. I'll be back with a definite duplicate.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: That is not a duplicate. He clearly knows that he cannot write to the literal, but he is asking if he can point to a different literal (although he might not know that he is asking it). Not sure why -3 here... the user might not know what the difference is, but the question is proper.

Comment: Thanks David. @Mats, I actually google-d and checked stackoverflow before asking. I understand that related questions were asked but I couldn't find which exactly answered this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `p` points to constant string literal so if you do: `p[1] = 'w';` then you are trying to modifying string literal that is read only **constant** and its illegal operation (Undefined behavior).

Whereas in expression `p = "OrangeTorange";` you modify value of `p` **variable** that is pointer to a char. And assigning new address value to `p` is a valid operation, now `p` start pointing to new string literal.

To add further, Suppose if `p` points an array then  `p[1] = 'w';` is not a invalid operation consider below example code:

```
char str[] = "Apple";
char* p = str; // p points to a array 
p[1] = 'w';    // valid expression, not str[1] = 'w' is well valid. 
p = "OrangeTorange";   // is valid
// str = "OrangeTorange"; is NOT valid as `str` is not a pointer but array name
```

Here both operations asked are valid!

**Note:** Two declarations `char *str` and `char str[]` are different. To understand it read: [What does sizeof(&arr) return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-return/15177499#15177499)

Answer (score 3):

`p[1] = 'w'` is attempting to modify a string literal, which is illegal. `p = "OrangeTorange"` is just assigning a different string literal to `p`, which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the original string because it's read-only data. You can modify the pointer to point to a different string because the pointer is modifiable. That is, `p = "OrangeTorange"` is not modifying the original string, only changing where the pointer `p` points to.