# Sizes of arrays declared with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof

```
char c[] = "Hello";
char *p = "Hello";

printf("%i", sizeof(c)); \\Prints 6
printf("%i", sizeof(p)); \\Prints 4
```

My question is:

Why do these print different results? Doesn't `c[]` also declare a pointer that points to the first character of the array (and therefore should have size 4, since it's a pointer)?

Comment: Pointers are not the same as arrays.

Comment: This may help: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html

Comment: read: [What does sizeof(&arr) return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-return/15177499#15177499)

Comment: This is one of the few exceptions to the rule that the name of an array is converted/decay to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're confused between pointers and arrays. Pointers and arrays (in this case `char *` and `char []`) are [not the same thing.](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)

- An array `char a[SIZE]` says that the value at the location of `a` is an array of length `SIZE`
- A pointer `char *a;` says that the value at the location of `a` is a pointer to a `char`. This can be combined with pointer arithmetic to behave like an array (eg, `a[10]` is 10 entries past wherever `a` points)

In memory, it looks like this (example taken from [the FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)):

```
 char a[] = "hello";  // array

   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
a: | h | e | l | l | o |\0 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+

 char *p = "world"; // pointer

   +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
p: |  *======> | w | o | r | l | d |\0 |
   +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

It's easy to be confused about the difference between pointers and arrays, because in many cases, an array reference "decays" to a pointer to it's first element. This means that in many cases (such as when passed to a function call) arrays become pointers. If you'd like to know more, [this section of the C FAQ describes the differences in detail](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

One major practical difference is that the compiler knows how long an array is. Using the examples above:

```
char a[] = "hello";  
char *p =  "world";  

sizeof(a); // 6 - one byte for each character in the string,
           // one for the '\0' terminator
sizeof(p); // whatever the size of the pointer is
           // probably 4 or 8 on most machines (depending on whether it's a 
           // 32 or 64 bit machine)
```

Answer (score 1):

The two operands to `sizeof` have different types. One is  an array of `char`, the other a pointer to `char`.

The C standard says that when the `sizeof` operator is applied to an array, the result is the total number of bytes in the array. `c` is an array of six `char` including the `NUL` terminator, and the size of `char` is defined to be 1, so `sizeof (c)` is 6.

The size of a pointer, however, is implementation-dependent. `p` is a pointer to `char`. On your system, the size of pointer to `char` happens to be 4 bytes. So that's what you see with `sizeof (p)`.

If you try `sizeof(*p)` and `sizeof(*c)`, however, they will both evaluate to 1, because the dereferenced pointer and the first element of the array are both of type `char`.

Answer (score 0):

They don't print the same because arrays and pointers are just not the same. There's no reason why they should be the same. An array is implicitly converted to a pointer in many circumstances, but this doesn't make them identical.

Answer (score 0):

"sizeof" is the directive of the compilers. The result indicates the size in memory that the argument occupies. Compiler is reseponsible for determining the result according to the argument's type. Regarding the "array", returns the array size. moreover, the pointer returns "4" generally speaking for 32-bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

pointer and array are different.

`char c[] = "Hello";`  //declare c as an array. sizeof(c) calculate the size of array 6.
`char *p = "Hello";`  //declare p as a pointer.sizeof(p) calculate the size of pointer,in most machine the size of pointer is 4.

you can also refer to <[c traps and pitfall](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201179288)>.