# What is the meaning of "float *newAudio"

Tags: objective-c

Sorry for my newbie question. Please refrain from down voting me because I am learning C. I am an experienced programmer on other languages, but not on C. I am trying to learn C at the same time I am trying to understand a library for iOS called Novaine, on Github.

This library has a module with the following signature:

```
Novocaine *audioManager = [Novocaine audioManager];

[audioManager setInputBlock:^(float *newAudio, UInt32 numSamples, UInt32 numChannels) {

}];
```

So, the internal block is receiving `numSamples`, `numChannels` and `newAudio` and `newAudio` is of kind float pointer?

What kind of object is this? an array of floats? if this is an array, how do I access its values? How do I know the number of elements it has?

Comment: I understand you're learning [tag:c], but, this is not [tag:c] code. It's [tag:objective-c] and it's a completely different thing. You should start by learning the difference perhaps. What you ask can be answered by a [tag:c] programmer too, but it's way to broad for SO. As I see it, if you don't know what pointers are, you should "*refrain*" from writing code by the time being, and search for a good resource to read about pointers. SO Also, does not provide information about that so GOOGLE it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sizes of arrays declared with pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18414310)

Comment: @JohnDoe that's pointer to float. It's meaning is defined by that drug library, just find source of `setInputBlock` method there.

Comment: @JohnDoe I am sorry, it was not  my intention. And I am even more sorry, because [you are apparently wrong](http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/pointers-in-objective-c/225700236). You should be patient when asking here. I was trying to point out that you need to understand some basics before trying more advanced things. Again sorry to offend you. Also, you tagged with [tag:ios] and other tags related to [tag:objective-c] really. And This code is NOT [tag:c]. And I hope my level of the useless kindness that you want is 0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a pointer to float value. Nothing strange here. It is often use to point some area in memory. You don't know the size of this are. Might be a single float but also can be larger, continuous space in memory.

You don't know what type of object is stored there. `float` doesn't mean that floats are stored there. It could be declared as `void *` as well. Again, it is just a space in memory. By typing `float *` you just give the compile a hint that when you move `newAudio` pointer (doing or example `newAudio ++`) it will move a pointer by a `sizeof(float)` number of bytes.

Based on method fingerprint I assume that this is a pointer to the first element of some buffer which size is probably `numSamples` * `numChannels` * `size of single sample`

This part of memory should be allocated first, to make sure that it's reserved for you:

`float *newAudio = calloc(numSamples * numChannels, sizeof(float));`

Comment: You should not have `newAudio` in the call to `calloc()`. Otherwise, good.

Comment: @KenThomases: of course, thank you for pointing this out. Edited my answer.

Comment: @KenThomases - Thanks for your explanation. I am now figuring out the whole thing. Thanks.