# Pointer to pointer issue

Tags: c, pointers

I created a pointer to pointer and a `int` array, but when I try to access the array via my pointer to pointer, it skips some elements and moves by two elements at a time (eg: from 1 to 3).
Here is my code:

```
int main(void) {
    int c=10;
    int p[5]={2,3,5,6,8};
    int *x;
    int **y;
    x=p;
    y=&p;
    printf("p value is %d and p points to %d",p,&p);
    printf("\n x is %d \n",x[1]);
    printf("\n y is %d \n",y[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

When I print `y[1]` it will print 5 instead of 3 and `y[2]` is printed as 8. I can't think of the reason. Can any one help me on this? Pointer `x` is is working fine and moves along the correct elements as `x[0]=2`, `x[1]=3`, `x[5]=5`.
also can any one explain why i get same value for p and &p

Comment: Not `double pointer` correct word is `pointer to pointer`

Comment: I *love* double pints, especially when they're a real nice, hoppy IPA.

Comment: Try `y = &x;` You may have better luck. And print anything you're passing that should be a "pointer" with `%p`. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: Are you sure `p` is a pointer?

Comment: The trouble with the term `double pointer` is that it is ambiguous between `double *` and `sometype **`.  The term is used informally for the double-star notation (and triple pointer for uses of [`sometype ***`](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)), but it is probably better to use 'pointer to pointer' to avoid misinterpretation in formal contexts like SO questions.

Comment: you must getting error/warning for `y=&p;` as @WhozCraig commented you might probably wants `y = &x`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: OP is using C and not C++.

Comment: @AlokSave **Yes**, C ... ?? did not get you!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: `p` without a subscript is an `int *`.  There are numerous attempts to print pointers with the `%d` notation.  This is very bad on 64-bit systems, and not particularly good on 32-bit systems.

Comment: y[1] would be entirely different thing than what you expect it to be. It is represents the pointer next to pointer p in memory. Which would contain garbage value. when you will run it few times more you would see its value keeps changing

Comment: I don't think there is any ambiguity in "double pointer" - anyone at least remotely familiar with C or C++ knows it is a `double *`. Using it for `**` is completely illogical, the location of a location to a location is not "double location"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, this question has been answered and an answer has been accepted, but even the accepted answer does not explain the weird results the original poster was seeing: why do `y[1]` and `y[2]` print 5 and 8? Here is the explanation.

Original poster: What output do you get from the following statements?

```
printf ("Size of integer: %zu\n", sizeof (int));
printf ("Size of pointer: %zu\n", sizeof (int*));
```

I'm going to bet that the output is:

```
Size of integer: 4
Size of pointer: 8
```

In other words, I'm guessing that you're compiling on a 64-bit machine where the size of an integer is 4 bytes and the size of a pointer is 8 bytes. Based on that assumption, here's what is happening.

`p` is an array. With a few exceptions, when used in any expression, the array's name "decays" to a pointer to its first element. Any time you access the value of `p`, therefore, it will yield the address of its first element.

`&p` is one of those exceptions to the rule about arrays "decaying" to pointers. The address-of operator, when applied to an array's name, returns a pointer to the entire array--not a pointer to a pointer to the first element of the array.

What this means is that `p` and `&p` have the same value, but they are semantically very different. You will get the same value when you print:

```
 printf("p value is %p and p points to %p", p, &p);  // use %p and not %d for addresses
```

However, this does not mean that `p` and `&p` refer to the same thing. `p` is the address of first element of the array, i.e., `&p[0]`. On the other hand, `&p` is the address of the **entire array of 5 integers**.

So when you define `x` and `y` as follows:

```
int* x = p;
int** y = &p;
```

`x` is assigned a pointer to the first element of the array; `y` is assigned a pointer to the entire array. This is an important difference!

There is, moreover, a mismatch between how `y` is declared, and the value you're assigning to it. `&p` is of type `int (*) [5]`; a pointer to an array of 5 `int`. `y` is merely a pointer to a pointer to a single `int`. Your compiler should give you a warning about this mismatch. Mine does:

```
Warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'int**' from 'int (*) 5'
```

This mismatch explains the weird results while printing values of `y[1]` and `y[2]`. Let's look at what's going on with the values.

As you know, array subscripts are offsets from the beginning of the array:

```
x[0] == *(x + 0)
```

So `x[0]` yields the first element of the array, i.e., 2. Similarly

```
x[1] == *(x + 1)
```

But `x` is a pointer to int. So what is actually happining in the addition `x + 1`? Remember how pointer arithmetic works. Adding an integer to a pointer means you're actually adding that integer **times the size of the element pointed to.** In this case:

```
x + 1 == x + (1 * sizeof(int))
```

Since `sizeof(int)` is 4 on your system, the value of `x[1]` is the next integer in the array, which is 3.

So then, when you print `y[0]`, how is this evaluated?

```
y[0] == *(y + 0)
```

Hence, the value that is at the address pointed to by `y`, i.e., at the address of `p`, is printed. This is the first element of `p`, hence you get the result 2.

What happens when you print `y[1]`?

```
y[1] == *(y + 1)
```

But what is `y`? It is a `pointer to a pointer to an int`. So when you add 1 to `y`, the way pointer arithmetic works is it again adds 1 * the size of the type of the element pointed to.

```
y + 1 == y + (1 * sizeof (int*))
```

The size of an `int*` is 8 bytes, not four! So every time you increment `y` by 1, you're incrementing it by 8 bytes, or the size of *two* integers. Hence, when you dereference that value, you are getting not the next integer in the array, but the integer that is two away.

To explain more clearly: Let us assume that the array begins at element 1000. Then, because each `int` takes four bytes, the following is the case:

```
 Address      Element
-----------------------
  1000          2
  1004          3
  1008          5
  1012          6
  1016          8


 p == &p == x == y == 1000
 *x == *y == 2
```

When you add 1 to x, you are adding 1 * `sizeof(int)`, i.e., you are actually adding 4. So you get 1004, and `*(x + 1)`, or `x[1]`, gives you 3.

But when you add 1 to y, you are adding 1 * `sizeof(int*)`, i.e., you are actually adding 8. So you get 1008, and `*(y + 1)` gives you the element at address 1008, or 5.

This explains the output you are getting. This is NOT, however, a reasonable way to code. You should not expect that the size of a pointer is always going to be 8 bytes. You should not assign an `int (*) []` to an `int**`. You should not dereference a pointer to a pointer to an `int` and expect to get an `int` result. And **always heed compiler warnings**.

Comment: Delayed but Its Very good answer. Your answer is better as you emphasis on the part where OP doubt comes.

Answer (score 4):

This at least gives a clean compilation and uses `%p` to print pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int p[5]={2,3,5,6,8};
    int *x = p;
    int **y = &x;
    printf("p value is %p and the address of p is %p and p points to %d\n", (void *)p, (void *)&p, *p);
    printf("x[1] is %d\n", x[1]);
    printf("y[0] is the address %p\n", (void *)y[0]);
    printf("y[0][0] is %d\n", y[0][0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output (Mac OS X 10.8.4, GCC 4.8.1, 64-bit compilation):

```
p value is 0x7fff5a1a54d0 and the address of p is 0x7fff5a1a54d0 and p points to 2
x[1] is 3
y[0] is the address 0x7fff5a1a54d0
y[0][0] is 2
```

Comment: thanks i got it.y[1] points to the next memory address.since mine is a 64 bit. 2 int values are saved in the same memory block. correct

Comment: If you're using a 64-bit compilation, then usually, `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(Anything *) == 8`, so you can regard that as '2 `int` values are saved in one pointer' — it's a little sloppy, but is not sufficiently inaccurate to matter.

Answer (score 4):

Remember array name can easily decays into pointer to first element in most expressions.
`p[]`  array in memory is like (addresses are assumption):

```
  p 
 200   204 208  212  216 
+----+----+----+----+---+
|  2 |  3 | 5  | 6  | 8 |
+----+----+----+----+---+
  ▲    ▲    ▲    ▲    ▲
  |    |    |    |    | 
  p    p+1  p+2  p+3  p+3
```

After `x = p;`, `x` also pointer to first element.

```
  p 
 200   204 208  212  216 
+----+----+----+----+---+
|  2 |  3 | 5  | 6  | 8 |
+----+----+----+----+---+
 ▲ ▲   ▲    ▲    ▲    ▲
 | |   |    |    |    | 
 | p   p+1  p+2  p+3  p+3
 |
 x 
+----+
| 200|
+----+
```

In expression `y = &p;` , `&p` is pointer of array of type `int(*)[5]` and `y` is `int**`. (you must getting a warning (or error) compile with `-Wall`).

Read: [Difference between  `&p` and `p`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-return/15177499#15177499)

Because value-wise both `p` and `&p` are same so address value of `y` is also same as `p`.

```
  p 
 200   204 208  212  216 
+----+----+----+----+---+
|  2 |  3 | 5  | 6  | 8 |
+----+----+----+----+---+
 ▲ ▲   ▲    ▲    ▲    ▲
 | |   |    |    |    | 
 | p   p+1  p+2  p+3  p+3
 |
 x         y
+----+    +----+
| 200|    | 200|
+----+    +----+
 int*      int**
```

Your first printf:

```
 printf("p value is %d and p points to %d",p,&p);
```

Should be written as:

```
 printf("p value is %p and p points to %p", (void*)p, (void*)&p);
 //                  ^                  ^
```

Use `%p` instead of `%d` because you are printing addresses also typecast to `void*` is necessary because  `%p` expects `void*`. As I said value-wise `p` and `&p` are same both addresses are same.

Second printf:

```
printf("\n x is %d \n", x[1]);
```

Outputs: `3` as `x` points to first element in array `x[1]` == `*(x + 1)` == `3` (in my figures `x + 1` == 204).

Third printf:

```
printf("\n y is %d \n", y[0]);
```

Note `y` type is `int**` so `y[0]` == `*(y + 0)` = `*y` value stored at `y` type of `*y` is `int*`.
So again because `y[0]` is `int*` you should use `%p` instead of `%d`.

But the above printf statement prints value of first element that is: `2`.

Similarly `y[1]` prints `3` and `y[2]` prints `5`.

**Edit**

> When I print `y[1]` it will print `5` instead of `3` and `y[2]` is printed as `8`.

No, It outputs as I explained above Check @[codepade](http://codepad.org/vTaVOGoe) where `sizeof(int)` == `sizeof(int*)` probably in your system `sizeof(int*)` = twice of `sizeof(int)` (64-bit compiler) so when you add one you address next to next location.

As @WhozCraig commented:  Try `y = &x;` You may have better luck. And print anything you're passing that should be a "pointer" with `%p`.

Correct your code.

Comment: "In expression `y = &p;` , `&p` is pointer of array of type `int(*)[5]`, but in assignment `int(*)[5]` decays into `int**`." I am not sure this is correct. A pointer to an array is a pointer, not an array. So it will not decay. I think the assignment here is between incompatible pointer types and will cause erratic behavior. Please see my answer for a fuller discussion. Thanks!

Comment: @verbose user formatting tips for programming codes use as `\`int(*)[5]\`` . Let me read your comment again.

Comment: @verbose actually word decay is wrong here. Give me a minute I correct it

Answer (score 0):

I think you code cann't compile successfully.
The type of `&p` is `char (*p)[10]`, but the type of `y` is `char **`,

```
cannot convert from 'char (*)[10]' to 'char **'
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean `int` and not `char`? Also, though the mismatched pointer assignment will generate a warning, it will compile.

Comment: no matter `char` or `int`, in my compiler i have this error `cannot convert from 'char (*)[10]' to 'char **'`

Comment: What compiler are you using?