# Declaration and initialization of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, initialization, declaration

Why doesn't this work?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char ch[50];
ch[50]="manipulation";
puts(ch);
}
```

and why does this work?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char ch[50]="manipulation";
puts(ch);
}
```

By "it works" I mean i get the output i want, that is, printing of "manipulation"(without quotes) as standard output.

Comment: read [Difference between `char *str` and `char str[]` and how both stores in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarray-return/15177499#15177499)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because with the syntax:

```
ch[50]="manipulation";
```

You're assigning the string "manipulation" to the 50th element of ch. 
That's not possible because the array is composed of idividual characters, and you're assigning a string to a individual char. Also, ch has elements from 0 to 49, and there's not a 50th element.

If something's wrong with my explanation, please tell me. And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: most down-to-earth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

1. `ch[50] = "manipulation"` isn't valid syntax.  Closer would be `ch = "manipulation"`, but arrays aren't modifiable lvalues, so you can't assign to them.  Use `strcpy(3)`, or declare `ch` as a pointer instead:

   ```
   strcpy(ch, "manipulation");
   ```

   or

   ```
   char *ch;
   ch = "manipulation";
   ```
2. Your second example is an initialization, not an assignment expression.  This form creates an array `ch` and copies the provided string literal to initialize it.

Comment: No, in a declaration it means "initialization".  It has to be different from an expression so you can use it at global scope or to initialize objects with static storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign naked C arrays, that's why. The second case isn't assignment at all, but initialization.

If you do want to assign arrays, you can achieve this by wrapping them in a struct:

```
struct Char50 { char data[50]; };

struct Char50 x;
struct Char50 y = { "abcde" };
x = y;
puts(x.data);
```

The more idiomatic way of handling strings is `strcpy`, though, e.g. `strcpy(ch, "abcde");`, though you have to be careful about the destination buffer size.