# Removing character from string in place

Tags: c, string

I have been trying to remove characters from a string without using extra memory and soing it in place. I just tried removing character 'a' from a given input string but my code gives a segmentation fault .

Input- abca

Output-bc
Debugger says the segmentation error is in line "str[j]=str[i]". Please help me out :) Thanks

Here is the code

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void removest(char *str) 
{
  int i,j=0;
  int len=strlen(str);
  for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
       if(str[i]=='a')
    {
      i=i+1;
    }
      str[j]=str[i];
      j++;
    }
  str[j]='\0';
  printf("%s \n",str);
}

int main()
{
  char *str="abca";
  removest(str);
}
```

Comment: You can't change constant string.

Comment: Read [Difference between `char *str` and `char str[]` and how both stores in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarray-return/15177499#15177499)

Answer (score 2):

`char *str = "abca";` is wrong as `str` pointer to string literal. Use char array, it should be `char str[] = "abca";`.

Because `str` points to a const string literal and so an expression like `str[i] = 'F'` is an illegal expression (because it tries to modify the first character of a constant string), which causes [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) at runtime.

There are also one bug  in your logic as well. It is not logically correct to increment `i` again inside the for loop with `i` as variable. It should be coded as below.

```
for(i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    if(str[i] == 'a')
    {
        continue;
    }
    str[j] = str[i];
    j++;
}
```

Comment: check updated answer to describe a bit more main problem. Correct?

Comment: Thanks for giving more useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Output-bc Debugger says the segmentation error is in line "str[j]=str[i]".

in this part of code

```
if(str[i]=='a')
{
  i=i+1;
}
  str[j]=str[i];
```

when i value will len-1;

then it is incremented now str[i] goes out of bound than str size which will be error.