# Invalid characters in decrypted output using AES encryption with OpenSSL libcrypto EVP API and FUSE filesystem

Tags: openssl, aes

I'm working on an encryption/decryption program using AES encryption and OpenSSL.  I set up a FUSE filesystem between two local directories, one is the mirror directory and the other is the mount point, on my linux virtual machine.  I am working on modifying the read, write, and create functions in the fuse_operations struct so that when I open and read an encrypted file from the mount point directory, the plaintext should be displayed in the application's window.

I have a function called do_crypt that takes as input a file with text, an output file where the decrypted/encrypted text is supposed to go, an int for decrypting, encrypting, or passing through, and pass phrase to used to complete the actions. The is code is below:

```
#define BLOCKSIZE 1024
#define FAILURE 0
#define SUCCESS 1

extern int do_crypt(FILE* in, FILE* out, int action, char* key_str){
/* Local Vars */

/* Buffers */
unsigned char inbuf[BLOCKSIZE];
int inlen;
/* Allow enough space in output buffer for additional cipher block */
unsigned char outbuf[BLOCKSIZE + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
int outlen;
int writelen;

/* OpenSSL libcrypto vars */
EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
unsigned char key[32];
unsigned char iv[32];
int nrounds = 5;

/* tmp vars */
int i;

/* Setup Encryption Key and Cipher Engine if in cipher mode */
if(action >= 0){
if(!key_str){
    /* Error */
    fprintf(stderr, "Key_str must not be NULL\n");
    return 0;
}
/* Build Key from String */
i = EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha1(), NULL,
           (unsigned char*)key_str, strlen(key_str), nrounds, key, iv);
if (i != 32) {
    /* Error */
    fprintf(stderr, "Key size is %d bits - should be 256 bits\n", i*8);
    return 0;
}
/* Init Engine */
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv, action);
}    

/* Loop through Input File*/
for(;;){
/* Read Block */
inlen = fread(inbuf, sizeof(*inbuf), BLOCKSIZE, in);
if(inlen <= 0){
    /* EOF -> Break Loop */
    break;
}

/* If in cipher mode, perform cipher transform on block */
if(action >= 0){
    if(!EVP_CipherUpdate(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen, inbuf, inlen))
    {
        /* Error */
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
        return 0;
    }
}
/* If in pass-through mode. copy block as is */
else{
    memcpy(outbuf, inbuf, inlen);
    outlen = inlen;
}

/* Write Block */
writelen = fwrite(outbuf, sizeof(*outbuf), outlen, out);
if(writelen != outlen){
    /* Error */
    perror("fwrite error");
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    return 0;
}
}

/* If in cipher mode, handle necessary padding */
if(action >= 0){
/* Handle remaining cipher block + padding */
if(!EVP_CipherFinal_ex(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen))
    {
    /* Error */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    return 0;
    }
/* Write remainign cipher block + padding*/
fwrite(outbuf, sizeof(*inbuf), outlen, out);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
}

/* Success */
return 1;
}
```

The function works fine without using the fuse system.  Everything is encrypted/decrypted properly but when I use the read function to decrypt files in the fuse filesystem I get some invalid characters in the output.  I've tried 3 text editors to look at the files: sublime reads the output like any other file with no problem; geany won't open the file because it says it doesn't recognize the encoding and there are invalid characters; gedit shows the decrypted output but also some invalid chars represented as '/00/00/00'.  I do not know what these characters are.  I did some research and I believe them to be null characters but I don't know why they show up when I use the fuse functions and run decrypt but they don't show up in the output when not using it.

I've tried 2 different version for the read function: one way using an in-memory buffer to hold the contents.

```
static int xmp_read(const char *path, char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset,
        struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
  (void) fi;
  int res;

char fpath[PATH_MAX];
xmp_fullpath(fpath, path);//changes path to mirror directory

FILE *f;


FILE *tmpFile;
tmpFile = tmpfile();
f = fopen(fpath, "r");

do_crypt(f, tmpFile, DECRYPT, XMP_DATA->key_phrase);//function that decrypts/encrypts

rewind(tmpFile);
res = pread(fileno(tmpFile), buf, size, offset);//read the encrypted/decrypted output to the application buffer

fclose(f);
fclose(tmpFile);
return res;
}
```

The other way creates a temp file before doing encryption/decryption:

```
int res;
char fpath[PATH_MAX];
xmp_fullpath(fpath, path);
FILE *memstream;
char *membuf;
size_t memlen;
//off_t eob;
memstream = open_memstream(&membuf, &memlen);//create a dynamically allocated buffer in memory

FILE *f = fopen(fpath, "rb");

do_crypt(f, memstream, DECRYPT, XMP_DATA->key_phrase);

fflush(memstream);
fseek(memstream, offset, SEEK_SET);

res = fread(buf, 1, memlen, memstream);

return res;
```

My questions are:

1) Why am I getting invalid characters '/00/00' which appear to be null characters in my output when trying to decrypt a file?

2) Why am I able to view the file with one text editor but not the other?

Again encryption and pass-through work perfectly in the fuse system and I can open them up with all three text editors. And the do_crypt works perfectly when I'm not using fuse. But when I try to decrypt in the fuse read function I get the right decrypted text but I also get those invalid characters.  When I use the 'cat' terminal command the output does not include the invalid characters.

Here is a link to the full repo of code.
https://github.com/latitude98/CU-CS3753-PA4

Comment: It's probably [`sizeof()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarray-return) thats the culprit. Note that it depends on the editor/viewer what it does with non-printable characters like ASCII charcter `00`.

Comment: I mean "such as" instead of like - give me a bit of wine when I'm tired and I turn into a Canadian girl :P

Comment: haha I knew what you meant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common mistake doing data mutation like encryption/decryption at the VFS level (e.g via fuse) is failing to mutate (i.e. decrypt) files in the fuse getattr function before calling the underlying getattr() system call.

In your case, if the getattr() system call is passed the encrypted file instead of the unencrypted file, it will return the wrong file size (encrypted and decrypted files have different file sizes). A lot of programs rely on this file size being correct in order to know how much of the file to read, so if getattr() is returning the size of the encrypted file instead of the size of the unencrypted file, you will likely see errors like you describe.

Some programs (e.g. complex text editors) rely on knowing the file size when reading a file, and thus need a working getattr() in order to function. Utilities like 'cat' tend to use the more basic "read one byte at a time until I see an EOF" approach and are thus less reliant on the a correct file size. That may explain why some programs work fine (those that hunt for an EOF), but other do not (those that try to read  bytes).

There are a few VFS/fuse function other than the obvious one (i.e. read) that require you to call decrypt. As mentioned above, getattr is probably the most critical one. You may also want to look at truncate and open. Depending on how you implemented your filesystem, those may need some decrypt awareness as well.