# Is it necessary to supply the null character when declaring an character's array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

A string constant in C is stored as a character array, while creating such an array element by element, is it necessary to supply the null character.

I need to store a string constant, say, `S[number]=  "hello\n"`. A string constant is stored as a character array in C, further, such a string is terminated by a null character `'\0'`. While storing the phrase in an array, do I need to account for the null character and allocate an additional space or do I just need to mention the number of characters that I need to store?

Comment: it depends on value of number in declaration. it may add (in most cases) or may not add (in one valid declaration).

Answer (score 7):

If you are going to use C-string functions, like strlen, - then answer is *YES*. Your string should be null-terminated. If you introduce your custom functions to deal with string - you can store it however you like.

It's important to mention, that if you create an array using string constant, it reserves space for null-character automatically. E.g. output for the following code:

```
char s[] = "hello";
printf("%d", sizeof(s) / sizeof(char));
```

is

```
6
```

which is 5 for 'h, 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' and 1 for '\0'.

Comment: As an aside, sizeof(char) is redundant.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Why is it reduntant? If you imply, that we know sizeof(char) apriory - it's not a good practice to count on such assumptions in general.

Comment: @DenisKulagin We do know it, `sizeof (char)` is 1. Always.

Comment: @unwind It's not the point! You can omit it in production code, but if it's a sample, which my snippet definitely is, I better write it this way to emphasize, that *sizeof* returns number of bytes and not number of elements.

Comment: A char may (and if I may make a wild guess routinely will at some point in my life time) have more than 8 bits, but that will just indicate that it doesn't make any sense on that [machine|cloud|fuzzy hybrid borg computational entity] to address or move around less than n (n>8) bits and nobody cares about the wasted space. Because the space is vast and empty, yet. Even then sizeof(char) == 1 will hold.

Comment: @DenisKulagin Sure, it's idiomatic for number of elements in an array. Still, I think it's better to write it `sizeof s / sizeof *s` in that case, stops you from repeating the type and (possibly) using the wrong type if the type of the array changes.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Just to clarify, even on those machines, `sizeof (char)` will be 1.

Comment: @unwind: True. That was my point but I may not have made it clear enough :-)

Comment: More importantly, this causes undefined behaviour as `size_t` does not match `%d` ... either cast the value to `(int)`, or use `%zu` in C99 or later.

Comment: @MattMcNabb In Microsoft's compiler %zu is not exists then `%lu` should be used

Comment: @DenisKulagin: so if i define a char Array[len], you mean to say that the location Array[len] contains '\0' ? because my string will go from 0 to len-1.

Comment: @Mr. Sherlock. If you define a char array of size *len*, then null-character should be put to index *len - 1*. Which means, that you have one less byte for your string contents. E.g. to store string "hello" you should do: **char s[6] = "hello";** Otherwise it will result in errorneous and unpredictable behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

> While storing the phrase in an array, do I need to account for the null character and allocate an additional space or do I just need t mention the number of characters that I need to store?

**Yes**, you should count null chars to allocate additional space. You must note Important point here:

```
S[number]= "hello\n";
```

Will append  `\0`  in `S[]` array if `number` value is equals to (or grater than) length of string `"hello\n"` pule one for `\0` char (or if you don't give size at all as `s[] = "hello\n";`).

From: ISO/IEC 9899:201x Committee Draft April 12, 2011 N1570:

> #### [6.7.9 [Initialization]](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html)
>
> [...]
>   14: An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF-8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (*including the terminating null character **if there is room or if the array is of unknown size***) initialize the elements of the array.
>   [..]
>   EXAMPLE 8       The declaration
>
> ```
> char s[] = "abc", t[3] = "abc";
> ```
>
> defines ``plain'' char array objects s and t whose elements are initialized with character string literals. This declaration is identical to:
>
> ```
>   char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' },
>        t[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' }; // you are missing this point
> ```
>
> The contents of the arrays are modifiable. On the other hand, the declaration
>
> ```
>  char *p = "abc";
> ```
>
> defines `p` with type `pointer to char'' and initializes it to point to an object with type`array of char'' with length 4 whose elements are initialized with a character string literal. If an attempt is made to use p to modify the contents of the array, the behavior is undefined.

So as I commented to your question: it depends on value of `number` you give in declaration in declaration. it *may* add `'\0'` char (in most cases) or *may not* add (in one valid declaration). This is very important point that most answers are missing.

More preciously:

Note `"hello"` is six char long string (including string termination nul char `'\0'` )

```
S[6]= "hello";
```

is same as:

```
S[6]= {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
// ^ is 6
```

But

```
S[5]= "hello";
```

is **valid** in C, But **don't append** nul `\0` char. It is equivalent to:

```
S[5]= {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
// ^  is 5
```

Now this is very important to note, In this declaration, if size is given five = 5 in declaration then you can use loop to print chars as `for(i = 0; i < sizeof(S); i++)`, but you can't use `%s` or functions like strcpy on `S[]` — using this call undefined behavior.

Beside this, I would also suggest you always use -Wall and -pedantic flag when you compiles your code. Now see how this works:

Lets compile this code, with `char s[4] = "hello";` :

```
int main(){
  char s[4] = "hello";
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof s; i++) 
   printf("%c", s[i]);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

You will get a warning as follows:

```
$ gcc -Wall -pedantic x.c
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:3:15: warning: initializer-string for array of chars is too long 
[enabled by default]
```

But code is valid in C with `char s[5] = "hello";` compile same code it will not give any warning to you that also implies it is a valid code but obviously it don't add `\0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  char s[5] = "hello";
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof s; i++) 
   printf("%c", s[i]);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Check this (you should notice this time compiler don't emits any warning):

```
$ gcc -Wall -pedantic x.c
@:~$ ./a.out 
hello
```

But this time we should use `printf("%s", s);` it will call undefined behavior.

So when you create an array with string literal then better is to avoid size in declaration, as:

```
  char s[] = "hello";
```

But this is just same as `char s[6] = "hello";` And you *can't* append a new char(s) to `s[]` as `strcat(s, " world!")`.

If you intended to modify `s[]` latter in your code then you may like to create a string of sufficiently large size as:

```
 char s[100] = "hello";
```

Now `strcat(s, " world!")` is perfectly valid code.

Comment: sir, suppose, i have allocated a char array as follows s[1000] and i now wish to store "hello\n" in it, so, in order for the program to take it as a string hello and then a new line, i must make the following assignments 
s[0]="h",s[1]="e",s[2]="l",s[3]="l",s[4]="o",s[5]="\n",s[6]="\0" ? what would be the issues i would face in case i don't make the last assignment?

Comment: @Mr.Sherlock Yes, if you declares `char s[1000];` then contents of `s[]` are garbage that time you have to explicitly store `'\0'` as `s[6] = '\0'` (note use single **`'`**, not double `"` for chars). You could also use strcpy function as `strcpy(s, "hello\n");` Now you may like to read this answer [What does sizeof(&array) return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarray-return/15177499#15177499) In which I tried to explain strings

Comment: @Mr.Sherlock Point to be note `"1"` is a string, `'1'` is a char, `1` is an singed integer, `1u` or `1U` are unsigned integer one. All are different.

Comment: correctly pointed out, my bad. thank you sir. just another doubt that i forgot to ask earlier. is char S[6]="hello\n" a valid assignment as a string ?

Comment: @Mr.Sherlock Yes `char S[6]="hello\n"` is valid in C (but not in C++). Important point to note as I explained in my answer if you decelerates `S[]` as `char S[6]="hello\n"` then `'\0'`  terminating null char **is not** append in `S[]` this declaration is same as `S[6]= {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\n'};` (no null termination) and you must not use it in `printf()` with `%s`, or string.h functions like `strlen()` because these excepts a null terminated strings. I would suggest you read my answer again.

Comment: yes sir i did, and that's why asked again to conform. 
Thank You very much :)

Answer (score 2):

No, but you should leave out `number`

```
char S[]= "hello\n";
```

will have the trailing 0 character and the array sized as needed.

With `number` too small you could accidentally cut off the 0 character.