# Understanding char array[] and string

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, char

I am new to programming. I am learning C as my first programming language. I found something strange to understand.

I have learnt that in C we can represent a String as a sequence of characters like this (using a char array):

```
char status[10] = "Married";
```

I have learnt that the problem of this approach is that we have to tell the size of the `status` array during compilation.

But now I have learned we can use a `char` pointer to denote an `string`  like -

```
char status[10] = "Married";
char *strPtr;
strPtr = status;
```

I don't understand it properly. My questions are -

1. How can I get char at index 4 (that is **i** in **Married**) using the `strPtr`?
2. In `status` there is a null character (`\0`) at the end of the `string` represented by the `char` array - `M`-`a`-`r`-`r`-`i`-`e`-`d`-`\0`. So by using the null character (`\0`) we can understand the end of the string. When we use `strPtr`, how can we understand the end of the `string`?

Comment: 1) `*(strPtr+4)` will give you the char `i`. 2) `strPtr` is also pointing to `status` so it'll have the (same) null character (`\0`) at the end.

Comment: Because arrays decays to pointers to their first elements, arrays and pointers can often be used interchangeably, so using the dereference operator on an array will work, as will using the array-indexing operator on a pointer. Also, `*(arrayOrPointer + X)` is equivalent to `arrayOrPointer[X]`.

Comment: check [What does `sizeof(&array)` return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarray-return/15177499#15177499)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
char *strPtr;
strPtr = status;
```

Now your pointer `strPtr` is pointing to the first character in the array and you can do

```
int i =0;
while( strPtr[i] != '\0')
{
  printf("%c ",strPtr[i]);
  i++;
}
```

`*strPtr` is called dereferencing the pointer to get the value stored in the location the pointer is pointing to.

Make a note that

```
strPtr[4] = *(strPtr +4);
```

Both will get you the value stored at the index 4 of the array.

**Note the difference between a pointer and a array name:**

```
----------------------------------
| s  | t  | r  | i  | n | g | \0 |
----------------------------------
  |
strPtr
status
```

`strPtr ++` will make your pointer point to the next element in the array.

```
| s  | t  | r  | i  | n | g | \0 |
----------------------------------
       |
      strPtr
```

Whereas you can't do this for the array name

`status++` is not allowed because [an array is not a modifiable lvalue](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/arraylval.html).

Comment: Wow! that means we can use pointer name- `strPtr` as an array? I will try it now. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @KajolK Check the edits to get the difference between an array and a pointer

Comment: In C, an array index is just a dereference of a pointer after addition: `x[i]` just means `*(x + i)`.

Comment: @KajolK; Always remember [pointers are not arrays and vice-versa](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html).

Comment: @KajolK: No, it means that the indexing operator `[]` requires a pointer, not an array, as one of its operands. Often that pointer will be the result of the implicit conversion of an array name.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `status[10]` is mere syntactic sugar for `*(status+10)`.

The `\0` termination is used under the hood to check for the end, if you were implementing some string-handler yourself you could do this too, or you could ignore it and use some other parameter `size` given with the string, or you could (don't!) choose anything else as the termination symbol.

This isn't just true of `char` arrays, or 'strings', a C array is just a pointer to a contiguous block of like-typed stuff with a compile-time check that your 'array' subscripts don't go beyond the 'end' specified at time of declaration. With the `*(array+offset)` notation, you need to check this for yourself.

Comment: @MattMcNabb `status[10]` is not undefined behavior here; the standard defines dereferencing _one past_ the last element of the array.

Comment: @BlacklightShining it only defines that if there is guaranteed to be allocated memory at that location (and some other conditions are true), which is not the case with `char status[10];`

Comment: `status[10]` means the same thing as `*(status+10)` anywhere _except_ in the specific kind of context the question is asking about.

Answer (score 4):

Good to know:

```
char status[10] = "Married";
```

is just *syntax sugar* for the equivalent:

```
char status[10]; // allocate 10 Bytes on stack
status[0] = 'M';
status[1] = 'a';
...
status[6]= 'd';
status[7] = '\0'; // same as 0
```

Nothing more, nothing less.

Also:

```
char c = status[3];
```

is *exactly* the same as

```
char c = *(status+3);
```

Comment: Except `new` doesn't allocate memory dynamically here, so it should be `new (some address in .data or .rodata) char[10];`

Comment: I am not sure, is there any 'new' keyword in c? Or should I have to use C++ for this?

Comment: @KajolK: There's now `new` in C. If you want to allocate string dynamically you need `malloc()`.

Comment: well, I've done too much C#. Edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt true, I changed my answer. Thanks

Comment: @che There's no `new` in C. * (I spent far too long looking for the version of C with a `new` keyword…)

Answer (score 3):

To get character at index 4 `strPtr`, you just use `strPtr[4]` (this also work for `status`).

To get the end of the string when using `strPtr`, you need to go through the characters and look for the terminating `\0`. This is what `printf("%s", strPtr)` does when it prints the string (and also when it parses the `"%s"` expression, which is just another string). To find a number of valid characters in the string in C, you use `strlen()` function. Oh, and make sure you dont do something like this:

```
char a[3];
strcpy(a, "Hello!");
```

As this will write 7 bytes into a three-byte memory space, and hence overwrite something you don't want overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to make a provocative statement: the way to think of this is that *`C` doesn't have strings*. `C` only has arrays of `char`. And despite its name, `char` is actually a *numeric* type (`'A'`, for example, is just a funny way to write a number, usually 65).

An array of `char` is not really different from an array of `int` or any other array of numeric type; it's just that the language offers some extra ways to write objects of type `char` and arrays of them, and there is a general convention (systematized with functions like `strlen`) for how to interpret data stored in `char` arrays as being representations of strings.

```
char status[10];     // declares an array of `char` of length 10. 
char *strPtr;        // declare a pointer to `char`
strPtr = status;     // make `strPtr` point to the first element of `status`

// Declare an array of 6 `char`, and initialize it.
char hello[6] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};

// Shorthand notation for initializing an array of 6 `char` as above
char world[6] = "World";

// I want to store numeric data in this one!
char other[6] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

// "World" is shorthand for a constant array of 6 `char`. This is
// shorthand for telling the compiler to actually put that array in
// memory someplace, and initialize worldPtr to point to that memory.
const char *worldPtr = "World";

// This does the same thing as above. But it's still a *constant* array.
// You should *never* do this; it should be syntactically illegal to
// make a nonconstant `char*` to point to it. This is only allowed for
// historical reasons.
char *helloPtr = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 1):

The '\0' at the end of the string is a useless add-on designed for easy or safety. You can tell string last character by using 'sizeof' like this:

```
char status[] = "Married"; 

size_t szLastCharstatus = sizeof(status) / sizeof(status[0]) - 2;

char chLastChar = status[szLastCharstatus];
```

Detailed explanation:

```
sizeof(status)
```

Returns the number of bytes array occpuies.

```
sizeof(status[0])
```

Returns the number of bytes first element occupies (and so the rest).

The division between those 2 values gives us the number of elements in the array. To access the last element now we need to subtract one 2 times because elements in array count from zero and because the last character in the string is '\0'.

Also note that arrays are not pointers and vice-versa. Arrays have an implicit conversion to pointer of their first element, constant size and their own type. They can be passed around by pointers or by value (using structure hack is required for the second).

Note that I'm using '[size_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t)' which is a type-def of a variable storing some size of data.

Comment: That will give the number of element in the array, but not the length of the string contained in the array. Since only 8 characters are initialized, the last two will have indeterminate values and reading them will lead to undefined behavior. Also note that this only works on "proper" arrays, once an array has decayed to a pointer the `sizeof` trick will no longer work. And the terminator character is not useless, all the standard C string functions rely on it being there.

Comment: Also note that the question is tagged `C`, so no `std` namespace.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg However it's a performance cost sometimes and avoiding it requires complex syntax. The trick will work as long as arrays are passed either by value or pointer.

Also fixed for 'C'.

Comment: The trailing nullbyte isn't useless at all—because of pointer decay, it's actually the _only_ way to find the end of the string if it's e.g. passed to a function as an argument.