# Difference between char * and char (*)[25]

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[25] = "Hello World";
    printf("%s\n", &str+2);
    printf("%p\n",&str);
    printf("%p\n",&str+2);
    return 0;
}
```

The program above flashes an error for line 6 saying:

```
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[25]’ [-Wformat=]
```

I wonder what's the difference between these two. And the output always shows two addresses having a difference of 32 bytes. I was expecting an output with a difference of 2 as I'm trying to print the address of `str` and address of `str`+2. Can you explain?

Comment: some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarray-return/15177499#15177499

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research I came up with this explanation. `&str+2` is treated as a pointer to an array. `char (*)[25]` says that it's a pointer to a character array of size 25. To find the explain to why the output shows 32 byte difference I ran the program again and notices the output was displayed in hex ie

```
0x7ffd865b2710
0x7ffd865b2742
```

When converted to base 10, it becomes a difference of 50 bytes which is a pointer to the array that lies at second place to the current array(remember &str+2). TO make it more clear here's a little memory diagram.

```
&str   -----> current array ie str. array is 25 bytes long.
&str+1 -----> array lies after 1 position to current array. This address is 25 bytes away from &str.
&str+2-----> array lies after 2 position to current array. This address is 50 bytes away from &str.
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference for this two cases is quite simple. Assume that we have an array of 25 characters: `char arr[25];`. By convention expression `arr` evaluated to a pointer to first array element, i.e. `arr` is the same  as `&arr[0]`. Note, that here unary operator `&` is applied to lvalue `arr[0]` which has type of `char`. And as result `&` gives an expression with type `char *` (i.e. pointer to `char`)

When we say `&arr` - the lvalue is `arr`, that is `char [25]` (i.e. array of 25 characters). And as result the whole expression has type `char (*)[25]` (i.e. pointer to array of 25 characters). So, we've got expression with completely another type, that is not compatible with `char *`.

Few notes about indexing. Difference between `&arr + 2` and `&arr` is 50 bytes (0x32 in hexadecimal), because `sizeof(arr) == 25`.

Answer (score 1):

`char *` is a pointer to `char` while `char (*)[25]` is a pointer to an array of 25 `char`'s so these types are different and the compiler rightfully issues a warning.

Moreover, since `&str` is the address of the `str` array and is of type `char (*)[25]`, the value of `&str+2` will be equal to:

```
&str + 2*sizeof(char (*)[25]) = &str + 2*25 = &str + 50 = &str + 0x32
```

Since a pointer is incremented according to the type it points to.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: after OP added a new line 6.

This is the correct syntax to print a string and pointer values. In all cases there was a `&` where it should not be, because a reference to the array identifier decays it to a pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[25] = "Hello World";
    printf("%s\n", str+2);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)str);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)(str+2));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
llo World
0018FF20
0018FF22
```

EDIT 2: This shows the effect of passing the pointer of the array. The compiler thinks you are addressing the third element of an array of strings each size 25. I have contrived to show how this undefined behaviour actually manifested.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[25] = "Hello World";
    char abc[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    printf("%s\n", &str+2);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
wxyz
```

Comment: The question asks for an explanation. But you'd better search for a dup...

Comment: You want a syntax error explaining? I did that by giving the correct syntax.

Comment: @WeatherVane : What was the problem with my program? I want to know the reason to why the compiler raised the error. Thanks for the correct answer though.

Comment: You have no idea. That's fine. Just be honest.

Comment: MSVC compiler does not give a warning or an error, but does not give a sensible result.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I have been trying to contrive some code that shows how `&str[25]` is treated as an array of that size, but did not yet make anything to demonstrate.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I have added a bit more.

Comment: @WeatherVane, are you sure it is `printf("%s\n", &str+2);` and not `printf("%p\n", &str+2);`?  [Cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/6rhu) throws a warning.

Comment: @BatCoder OP asked for an explanation of the warning from line 6 `printf("%s\n", &str+2);` that is using the `%s` format, and also asked why the other two lines don't give addresses that differ by 2. Although it is the same error in all three lines.