# Difference in size of a pointer to a string, and sizeof a a string

Tags: c++, string, pointers, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about pointers and strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380090/question-about-pointers-and-strings-in-c)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()   
{    
char *str1="abcd";  
char str2[]="abcd";  
printf("%d %d %d\n",sizeof(str1),sizeof(str2),sizeof("abcd"));  
return 0;
}
```

Why does this code give same answers for `sizeof(str2)` and `sizeof("abcd")` even when `str2` is ideally just like a pointer to a string , as is `str1` ,so answer should be 4 4 5

Code on Ideone:
http://ideone.com/za8aV

Answer: 4 5 5

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't answer my question,why shouldn't str2 be same as str1 (in it's definition of being a pointer to a string)

Comment: The first one is a pointer the second one is an array. A *pointer* and an *array*. They are two completely different things. That's why they "should not be the same". Why do you expect two completely different things to behave the same way? You know, it is very difficult to answer questions like this, when it is virtually impossible to even begin to understand why you find this behavior strange. You are basically asking "why cars are different from apples". How can one answer such a question?

Comment: hmm.. got it ,str2[] is equivalent to "abcd" in being an array of characters while str1 is a pointer , then can you please clear a doubt what exactly is str2[] , is it a pointer or a string?

Comment: `str2` is an object of type `char [5]` (an array of 5 `char`s). In your example it happens to store string `"abcd"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get the idea that `str2` is "ideally just like a pointer to a string"? It is not. `str2` is an array. When operator `sizeof` is applied to an array, it returns the size of the array object in bytes.

String literal is also an array, so when `sizeof` is applied to a string literal, it returns the size of that array object in bytes. So, it is perfectly natural to expect `sizeof("abcd")` and `sizeof(str2)` to produce the same result. And they do.

**P.S.** `%d` is not an appropriate format specifier to print the result of `sizeof`. `%d` requires `int` argument, while `sizeof` produces a `size_t` value. Use `%zu` to print values of `size_t` type.

Comment: Use `std::ostream`, and don't worry about the actual types.

Comment: @James Kanze: It is actually an interesting question. Does `std::ostream` guarantee that it "knows" how to output values of `size_t` type? Of course, it has `<<` overloads for all built-in integral types, but `size_t` can be defined as a non-standard implementation-specific unsigned integral type. Granted, some suitable conversion will probably make it work in any case, but anyway...

Comment: I don't have access to the C standard here.  The Posix standard requires that `size_t` not be larger than `long`; the page claims compatibility with the C standard here, but the way the requirement is worded makes me doubt; the language of the paragraph with this constraint is very unlike that of the C standard.  For the rest: in practice, `size_t` will be one of the standard integral types, but it does look like there is an oversight on the part of the C++ standards committee: I would expect that `<<` be required for all extended integral types as well.

Answer (score 4):

An array of characters is not a `char` pointer. Although arrays do decay to pointers when passed to functions, they are essentially different things (specifically, the compiler knows their exact length at compile time). The reason you see 5 for a four-character string is that string literals reserve one more `char` for the terminating zero. `4`, on the other hand, is system-dependent: on systems with 32-bit pointers you will see `4`, while on system with 64-bit pointers you will see `8`

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char *str1="abcd";
char str2[]="abcd";
printf("%c %c\n",*str1,*str2);
printf("%d %d %d\n",sizeof(str1),sizeof(str2),sizeof("abcd"));\
return 0;
}                                                                                  http://ideone.com/AZfCz    I'm getting the same output, a,a for both *str1 and *str2

Comment: Added the bit about exact size known at compile time.  It's important to explain the reasoning for the behavior, not just handwave and say "that's how it works."

Comment: @Wug Thanks, I was in the process of editing the answer adding more details - this is an important addition!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight could you please throw some more light on what you are trying to mean,according to my interpretation both str1 and str2 are pointers to a character string(array),and hence we should have an output as 4 4 5

Comment: @Dref D: Your interpretation is incorrect. `str1` is a pointer. `str2` is *not* a pointer. `str2` is an array. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @DrefD That is incorrect, `char str2[]` is not a pointer, it is an array with an implicitly defined size. It is the same as `char str2[5]` - the compiler lets you drop the `5`, because it can figure it out from the initializer, but that is the same thing. A declaration `char str2[]` becomes a pointer only when it is a declaration of a function parameter: `void foo(char str2[])`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help...I see I had mixed the two..thanks for clearing my doubt @dasblinkenlight